# How to convert an enum to a string in modern C++

Tags: c++, string, enums, c++17, c++20

#### Contrary to all other similar questions, this question is about using the new C++ features.

- 2008 [c](/questions/tagged/c) [Is there a simple way to convert C++ enum to string?](/questions/201593)
- 2008 [c](/questions/tagged/c) [Easy way to use variables of enum types as string in C?](/questions/147267)
- 2008 [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [How to easily map c++ enums to strings](/questions/207976)
- 2008 [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [Making something both a C identifier and a string?](/questions/126277)
- 2008 [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [Is there a simple script to convert C++ enum to string?](/questions/201593)
- 2009 [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [How to use enums as flags in C++?](/questions/1448396)
- 2011 [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [How to convert an enum type variable to a string?](/questions/5093460)
- 2011 [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [Enum to String C++](/questions/6281461)
- 2011 [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [How to convert an enum type variable to a string?](/questions/5093460)
- 2012 [c](/questions/tagged/c) [How to convert enum names to string in c](/questions/9907160)
- 2013 [c](/questions/tagged/c) [Stringifying an conditionally compiled enum in C](/questions/18790332)

#### After reading many answers, I did not yet find any:

- Elegant way using [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) or [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) new features
- Or something ready-to-use in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/)
- Else something planned for [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20)

#### Example

An example is often better than a long explanation.
You can compile and run this snippet on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fd889116289d906).
<sup>([Another former example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb58819257b6df50) is also available)</sup>

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass
{
    enum class MyEnum : char {
        AAA = -8,
        BBB = '8',
        CCC = AAA + BBB
    };
};

// Replace magic() by some faster compile-time generated code
// (you're allowed to replace the return type with std::string
// if that's easier for you)
const char* magic (MyClass::MyEnum e)
{
    const std::map<MyClass::MyEnum,const char*> MyEnumStrings {
        { MyClass::MyEnum::AAA, "MyClass::MyEnum::AAA" },
        { MyClass::MyEnum::BBB, "MyClass::MyEnum::BBB" },
        { MyClass::MyEnum::CCC, "MyClass::MyEnum::CCC" }
    };
    auto   it  = MyEnumStrings.find(e);
    return it == MyEnumStrings.end() ? "Out of range" : it->second;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << magic(MyClass::MyEnum::AAA) <<'\n';
   std::cout << magic(MyClass::MyEnum::BBB) <<'\n';
   std::cout << magic(MyClass::MyEnum::CCC) <<'\n';
}
```

#### Constraints

- Please no valueless duplication of [other answers](/a/10177840/938111) or [basic link](/a/18791363/938111).
- Please avoid bloat macro-based answer, or try to reduce the `#define` overhead as minimum as possible.
- Please no manual `enum` -> `string` mapping.

#### Nice to have

- Support `enum` values starting from a number different from zero
- Support negative `enum` values
- Support fragmented `enum` values
- Support `class enum` (C++11)
- Support `class enum : <type>` having any allowed `<type>` (C++11)
- Compile-time (not run-time) conversions to a string,
  or at least fast execution at run-time (e.g. `std::map` is not a great idea...)
- [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) (C++11, then relaxed in C++14/17/20)
- [`noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) (C++11)
- [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17)/[C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20) friendly snippet

One possible idea could be using the C++ compiler capabilities to generate C++ code at compilation-time using meta-programming tricks based on `variadic template class` and `constexpr` functions...

Comment: You could consider customizing your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) thru your extension in MELT defining a `builtin_enum_name` ; but that would take days of work.

Comment: (maybe of-topic) look at this Qt related blog. http://woboq.com/blog/reflection-in-cpp-and-qt-moc.html. Describes a possibility of replacing Qt's moc(meta-object-compiler) by using C++ reflection(proposed standard).

Comment: There have been some interesting papers in the reflection study which ranged from exactly what you are trying to do to what you are trying to do and reflecting the rest of the language as well.

Comment: [N4113](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4113.pdf): `std::enumerator::identifier_v<MyEnum, MyEnum::AAA>`

Comment: I personally solved this problem by implementing a small preprocessor utility library that allows me to loop over variadic macro arguments and perform a function over all of them. I pass the enum values as macro arguments and I automatically generate the enum and the string array through the preprocessor. You can probably do this using Boost Preprocessor as well.

Comment: does everything have to be solved with C++? It's so easy to automatically generate code for the string representation, just a couple of lines of code.

Comment: Hi @VittorioRomeo. Do you want to suggest something requiring as much as lines of code as proposed by [Matthieu M.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10177840/938111)?

Comment: @olibre: Yes, exactly

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, If something like [`SANDBOX_DEFINE_ENUM`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10177840/938111) was part of Boost it could be a fallback-solution. From my point of view, the `SANDBOX_DEFINE_ENUM` overhead provides similar service as [P99_DECLARE_ENUM](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__types_ga5d811e46f48e01d79d1f931817d9c0f1.html#ga5d811e46f48e01d79d1f931817d9c0f1). However if you can provide an elegant Boost-based answer, why not! In this case, please feel free to answer. Your answer may be useful for some years until C++17 release, implemented and authorized by companies...

Comment: "Please do not provide C macro-based answers if possible " well, unless you are willing to wait for C++17 there is hardly anything usable, and it isn't *that* bad to declare your enums as `DEC_ENUM(enumname, (a,b,c,(d,b),(e,42)))` unless you have to maintaint the generating macro... and imho putting such cases into the language is only another kind of hack in lieu of a more powerful template/macro hybrid. We should not add all those useful usecases of macros into the language just to be able to say that macros have no use anymore.

Comment: @olibre: I'm not sure I'll have time to write a complete answer, but [here's my current implementation](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVUtils/blob/master/include/SSVUtils/FatEnum/FatEnum.hpp). I hope it can help :)

Comment: @olibre: maybe I need an anonymized account to not get the shame downvotes ;) I will try to extract it from our library...

Comment: @olibre: quite the contrary. I prefer code generation. it results in cleaner code.

Comment: @olibre: you can use c++ (lol), or preferably any portable "scripting" language: ruby, python, perl... whether you use C++ as input (with all the headaches of C++ parsing) and generate additional C++ code from it or use some other (domain specific) language as input is up to you... I guess, whatever makes sense.

Comment: Hi @VittorioRomeo. I think your code is much better than [the solution from PlasmaHH](/a/28838042/938111). You spend some time trying to reduce as much as possible the macro stuff overhead as much as possible... Let me know ;) Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way to convert C++ enum to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201593/is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-c-enum-to-string) Restricting to new versions does not change much since as soon as a new version allows something, someone will answer the older questions. Better concentrate all in one place IMHO.

Comment: Thanks @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功 for your cleanup work. However [Is there a simple way to convert C++ enum to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201593) has an answer since 2008 (almost 10 years ago). But this question does not yet have an usable answer. This current question is not about any "simple way", but about avoiding complicated pre-build generation or preprocessor directives => about the ultimate C++ dream : a solution 100% in C++ (e.g. without `#define`). Do you feel the difference? What do you advice I should change in the question to show this difference? Cheers

Comment: @olibre this question has at least two usable **answers** for today. 1. @ecatmur's nice answer about C++17, which we can't edit every time there is an update in the C++17 discussion. See the [mailing list of the reflection study group](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/reflection). 2. my answer with nice-ish syntax for current C++, which is used by many people in production, but uses `#define` internally. What you are asking is for a usable **solution**. Today's correct **answer** is that a fully "right" solution is not available until later (i.e. accept @ecatmur for now).

Comment: OK @antron I validate your very interesting answer. But when compiler will implement experimental C++ reflexion, we will update the ecatmur's answer to illustrate some examples. Then, her/his answer will become the valid one. Thanks for your feedback, Cheers ;-)

Comment: I'll just leave a comment on here that [Herb Sutters proposal on Metaclasses](https://herbsutter.com/2017/07/26/metaclasses-thoughts-on-generative-c/) looks promising. Here is an introductional video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nsyX37nsRs

Comment: I don't understand the last two bullet items. What is "snippet C++14/C++17?" In what sense can it be "C++ State of the art"?

Comment: My meaning was: (1) *snippet C++14/C++17 friendly* -> *Provide a short C++ example that uses some C++14/C++17 features*. (2) *C++ State of the art* -> *Provide some explanation about the new way to use C++ features in the purpose to convert enum to string*. I think the two last bullets are not actually understandable. Do you want to rephrase/delete/merge/complete them? Thanks for your last edition, you have clarified the question  :-)  Cheers

Comment: "Please no invaluable duplication of other answers or basic link." Should be "valueless duplication" right?

Comment: std::map could be std::unordered_map

Comment: @olibre somehow the author of `magic_enum` answered months before, but accepted answer is from somebody else. Imo, it would be fair to accept the original author's reply

Comment: Thank you very much @Pavel for your eyes, I searched for other answers about `magic_enum` but did not notice the author of `magic_enum` had answered using another of her/his libraries. I have temporally accepted her/his answer but I am expecting she/he completes it --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/55312360/938111

Comment: Are there any proposals for this as a language feature? Judging from the amount of likes for this question, and amount of similar questions, it would seem many people would like this feature implemented. Personally, I'm thinking about extending the `enum class` to allow us to write constructors (e.g. construct enum from a string), and utility methods such as the very popular `System.Object.ToString()` from C#. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

## [Magic Enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum) header-only library provides static reflection for enums (to string, from string, iteration) for C++17.

(Disclosure: I'm the author of the library.)

```cpp
#include <magic_enum.hpp>

enum Color { RED = 2, BLUE = 4, GREEN = 8 };

Color color = Color::RED;
auto color_name = magic_enum::enum_name(color);
// color_name -> "RED"

std::string color_name{"GREEN"};
auto color = magic_enum::enum_cast<Color>(color_name)
if (color.has_value()) {
  // color.value() -> Color::GREEN
};
```

For more examples check home repository https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum.

### Where is the drawback?

This library uses a compiler-specific hack (based on `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` / `__FUNCSIG__`), which works on Clang >= 5, MSVC >= 15.3 and GCC >= 9.

Enum value must be in range `[MAGIC_ENUM_RANGE_MIN, MAGIC_ENUM_RANGE_MAX]`.

- By default `MAGIC_ENUM_RANGE_MIN = -128`, `MAGIC_ENUM_RANGE_MAX = 128`.
- If need another range for all enum types by default, redefine the macro `MAGIC_ENUM_RANGE_MIN` and `MAGIC_ENUM_RANGE_MAX`.
- `MAGIC_ENUM_RANGE_MIN` must be less or equals than `0` and must be greater than `INT16_MIN`.
- `MAGIC_ENUM_RANGE_MAX` must be greater than `0` and must be less than `INT16_MAX`.
- If need another range for specific enum type, add specialization enum_range for necessary enum type.

  ```cpp
  #include <magic_enum.hpp>

  enum number { one = 100, two = 200, three = 300 };

  namespace magic_enum {
  template <>
    struct enum_range<number> {
      static constexpr int min = 100;
      static constexpr int max = 300;
  };
  }
  ```

Comment: Why the range limits? Is it to limit some kind of recursion depth, or because of some kind of compile-time linear search?

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you!  It's probably even efficient if the compiler is smart enough to evaluate the constexpr std::array one time only. Very very nice.

Comment: @EmileCormier The range limits are necessary because the library has to probe every possible value in the range to see if it corresponds to an enumerator. It instantiates an `is_valid` function template for every value in the range [-128, 127].

This can result in heavy compile times, so the range is quite conservative by default.

Here's a simplified version of the technique: https://godbolt.org/z/GTxfva

Comment: for me the most important drawback is that it fails silently: https://godbolt.org/z/TTMx1v There is restriction on size of values, but when the constrain is not met, there is no compile error, no exception, only empty string returned.

Comment: @Neargye will this won't have problem if i have enum with values outside of min/max range but i will only use the enum-to-string feature?

Comment: @acegs if a value outside of min/max range enum-to-string will return an empty string.

Answer (score 112):

<sub>(The approach of the [better_enums](https://github.com/aantron/better-enums) library)</sub>

There is a way to do enum to string in current C++ that looks like this:

```
ENUM(Channel, char, Red = 1, Green, Blue)

// "Same as":
// enum class Channel : char { Red = 1, Green, Blue };
```

Usage:

```
Channel     c = Channel::_from_string("Green");  // Channel::Green (2)
c._to_string();                                  // string "Green"

for (Channel c : Channel::_values())
    std::cout << c << std::endl;

// And so on...
```

All operations can be made `constexpr`. You can also implement the C++17 reflection proposal mentioned in the answer by @ecatmur.

- There is only one macro. I believe this is the minimum possible, because preprocessor stringization (`#`) is the only way to convert a token to a string in current C++.
- The macro is pretty unobtrusive – the constant declarations, including initializers, are pasted into a built-in enum declaration. This means they have the same syntax and meaning as in a built-in enum.
- Repetition is eliminated.
- The implementation is most natural and useful in at least C++11, due to `constexpr`. It can also be made to work with C++98 + `__VA_ARGS__`. It is definitely modern C++.

---

The macro's definition is somewhat involved, so I'm answering this in several ways.

- The bulk of this answer is an implementation that I think is suitable for the space constraints on StackOverflow.
- There is also a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1002895/Clean-Reflective-Enums-Enum-to-String-with-Nice-Sy) describing the basics of the implementation in a long-form tutorial. [*Should I move it here? I think it's too much for a SO answer*].
- There is a [full-featured library "Better Enums"](https://github.com/aantron/better-enums) that implements the macro in a single header file. It also implements [N4428 Type Property Queries](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4428.pdf), the current revision of the C++17 reflection proposal N4113. So, at least for enums declared through this macro, you can have the proposed C++17 enum reflection now, in C++11/C++14.

It is straightforward to extend this answer to the features of the library – nothing "important" is left out here. It is, however, quite tedious, and there are compiler portability concerns.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of both the CodeProject article and the library.

You can try the [code in this answer](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/x7YGZWuaMQ6gaxQ1), [the library](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5N9QZYdA5LqWy26R), and [the implementation of N4428](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pNEx7UEWqDtqFAwm) live online in Wandbox. The library documentation also contains an [overview of how to use it as N4428](http://aantron.github.io/better-enums/demo/C++17ReflectionProposal.html), which explains the enums portion of that proposal.

---

## Explanation

The code below implements conversions between enums and strings. However, it can be extended to do other things as well, such as iteration. This answer wraps an enum in a `struct`. You can also generate a traits `struct` alongside an enum instead.

The strategy is to generate something like this:

```
struct Channel {
    enum _enum : char { __VA_ARGS__ };
    constexpr static const Channel          _values[] = { __VA_ARGS__ };
    constexpr static const char * const     _names[] = { #__VA_ARGS__ };

    static const char* _to_string(Channel v) { /* easy */ }
    constexpr static Channel _from_string(const char *s) { /* easy */ }
};
```

The problems are:

1. We will end up with something like `{Red = 1, Green, Blue}` as the initializer for the values array. This is not valid C++, because `Red` is not an assignable expression. This is solved by casting each constant to a type `T` that has an assignment operator, but will drop the assignment: `{(T)Red = 1, (T)Green, (T)Blue}`.
2. Similarly, we will end up with `{"Red = 1", "Green", "Blue"}` as the initializer for the names array. We will need to trim off the `" = 1"`. I am not aware of a great way to do this at compile time, so we will defer this to run time. As a result, `_to_string` won't be `constexpr`, but `_from_string` can still be `constexpr`, because we can treat whitespace and equals signs as terminators when comparing with untrimmed strings.
3. Both the above need a "mapping" macro that can apply another macro to each element in `__VA_ARGS__`. This is pretty standard. This answer includes a simple version that can handle up to 8 elements.
4. If the macro is to be truly self-contained, it needs to declare no static data that requires a separate definition. In practice, this means arrays need special treatment. There are two possible solutions: `constexpr` (or just `const`) arrays at namespace scope, or regular arrays in non-`constexpr` static inline functions. The code in this answer is for C++11 and takes the former approach. The CodeProject article is for C++98 and takes the latter.

---

## Code

```
#include <cstddef>      // For size_t.
#include <cstring>      // For strcspn, strncpy.
#include <stdexcept>    // For runtime_error.



// A "typical" mapping macro. MAP(macro, a, b, c, ...) expands to
// macro(a) macro(b) macro(c) ...
// The helper macro COUNT(a, b, c, ...) expands to the number of
// arguments, and IDENTITY(x) is needed to control the order of
// expansion of __VA_ARGS__ on Visual C++ compilers.
#define MAP(macro, ...) \
    IDENTITY( \
        APPLY(CHOOSE_MAP_START, COUNT(__VA_ARGS__)) \
            (macro, __VA_ARGS__))

#define CHOOSE_MAP_START(count) MAP ## count

#define APPLY(macro, ...) IDENTITY(macro(__VA_ARGS__))

#define IDENTITY(x) x

#define MAP1(m, x)      m(x)
#define MAP2(m, x, ...) m(x) IDENTITY(MAP1(m, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MAP3(m, x, ...) m(x) IDENTITY(MAP2(m, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MAP4(m, x, ...) m(x) IDENTITY(MAP3(m, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MAP5(m, x, ...) m(x) IDENTITY(MAP4(m, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MAP6(m, x, ...) m(x) IDENTITY(MAP5(m, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MAP7(m, x, ...) m(x) IDENTITY(MAP6(m, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MAP8(m, x, ...) m(x) IDENTITY(MAP7(m, __VA_ARGS__))

#define EVALUATE_COUNT(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, count, ...) \
    count

#define COUNT(...) \
    IDENTITY(EVALUATE_COUNT(__VA_ARGS__, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1))



// The type "T" mentioned above that drops assignment operations.
template <typename U>
struct ignore_assign {
    constexpr explicit ignore_assign(U value) : _value(value) { }
    constexpr operator U() const { return _value; }

    constexpr const ignore_assign& operator =(int dummy) const
        { return *this; }

    U   _value;
};



// Prepends "(ignore_assign<_underlying>)" to each argument.
#define IGNORE_ASSIGN_SINGLE(e) (ignore_assign<_underlying>)e,
#define IGNORE_ASSIGN(...) \
    IDENTITY(MAP(IGNORE_ASSIGN_SINGLE, __VA_ARGS__))

// Stringizes each argument.
#define STRINGIZE_SINGLE(e) #e,
#define STRINGIZE(...) IDENTITY(MAP(STRINGIZE_SINGLE, __VA_ARGS__))



// Some helpers needed for _from_string.
constexpr const char    terminators[] = " =\t\r\n";

// The size of terminators includes the implicit '\0'.
constexpr bool is_terminator(char c, size_t index = 0)
{
    return
        index >= sizeof(terminators) ? false :
        c == terminators[index] ? true :
        is_terminator(c, index + 1);
}

constexpr bool matches_untrimmed(const char *untrimmed, const char *s,
                                 size_t index = 0)
{
    return
        is_terminator(untrimmed[index]) ? s[index] == '\0' :
        s[index] != untrimmed[index] ? false :
        matches_untrimmed(untrimmed, s, index + 1);
}



// The macro proper.
//
// There are several "simplifications" in this implementation, for the
// sake of brevity. First, we have only one viable option for declaring
// constexpr arrays: at namespace scope. This probably should be done
// two namespaces deep: one namespace that is likely to be unique for
// our little enum "library", then inside it a namespace whose name is
// based on the name of the enum to avoid collisions with other enums.
// I am using only one level of nesting.
//
// Declaring constexpr arrays inside the struct is not viable because
// they will need out-of-line definitions, which will result in
// duplicate symbols when linking. This can be solved with weak
// symbols, but that is compiler- and system-specific. It is not
// possible to declare constexpr arrays as static variables in
// constexpr functions due to the restrictions on such functions.
//
// Note that this prevents the use of this macro anywhere except at
// namespace scope. Ironically, the C++98 version of this, which can
// declare static arrays inside static member functions, is actually
// more flexible in this regard. It is shown in the CodeProject
// article.
//
// Second, for compilation performance reasons, it is best to separate
// the macro into a "parametric" portion, and the portion that depends
// on knowing __VA_ARGS__, and factor the former out into a template.
//
// Third, this code uses a default parameter in _from_string that may
// be better not exposed in the public interface.

#define ENUM(EnumName, Underlying, ...)                               \
namespace data_ ## EnumName {                                         \
    using _underlying = Underlying;                                   \
    enum { __VA_ARGS__ };                                             \
                                                                      \
    constexpr const size_t           _size =                          \
        IDENTITY(COUNT(__VA_ARGS__));                                 \
                                                                      \
    constexpr const _underlying      _values[] =                      \
        { IDENTITY(IGNORE_ASSIGN(__VA_ARGS__)) };                     \
                                                                      \
    constexpr const char * const     _raw_names[] =                   \
        { IDENTITY(STRINGIZE(__VA_ARGS__)) };                         \
}                                                                     \
                                                                      \
struct EnumName {                                                     \
    using _underlying = Underlying;                                   \
    enum _enum : _underlying { __VA_ARGS__ };                         \
                                                                      \
    const char * _to_string() const                                   \
    {                                                                 \
        for (size_t index = 0; index < data_ ## EnumName::_size;      \
             ++index) {                                               \
                                                                      \
            if (data_ ## EnumName::_values[index] == _value)          \
                return _trimmed_names()[index];                       \
        }                                                             \
                                                                      \
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid value");                    \
    }                                                                 \
                                                                      \
    constexpr static EnumName _from_string(const char *s,             \
                                           size_t index = 0)          \
    {                                                                 \
        return                                                        \
            index >= data_ ## EnumName::_size ?                       \
                    throw std::runtime_error("invalid identifier") :  \
            matches_untrimmed(                                        \
                data_ ## EnumName::_raw_names[index], s) ?            \
                    (EnumName)(_enum)data_ ## EnumName::_values[      \
                                                            index] :  \
            _from_string(s, index + 1);                               \
    }                                                                 \
                                                                      \
    EnumName() = delete;                                              \
    constexpr EnumName(_enum value) : _value(value) { }               \
    constexpr operator _enum() const { return (_enum)_value; }        \
                                                                      \
  private:                                                            \
    _underlying     _value;                                           \
                                                                      \
    static const char * const * _trimmed_names()                      \
    {                                                                 \
        static char     *the_names[data_ ## EnumName::_size];         \
        static bool     initialized = false;                          \
                                                                      \
        if (!initialized) {                                           \
            for (size_t index = 0; index < data_ ## EnumName::_size;  \
                 ++index) {                                           \
                                                                      \
                size_t  length =                                      \
                    std::strcspn(data_ ## EnumName::_raw_names[index],\
                                 terminators);                        \
                                                                      \
                the_names[index] = new char[length + 1];              \
                                                                      \
                std::strncpy(the_names[index],                        \
                             data_ ## EnumName::_raw_names[index],    \
                             length);                                 \
                the_names[index][length] = '\0';                      \
            }                                                         \
                                                                      \
            initialized = true;                                       \
        }                                                             \
                                                                      \
        return the_names;                                             \
    }                                                                 \
};
```

and

```
// The code above was a "header file". This is a program that uses it.
#include <iostream>
#include "the_file_above.h"

ENUM(Channel, char, Red = 1, Green, Blue)

constexpr Channel   channel = Channel::_from_string("Red");

int main()
{
    std::cout << channel._to_string() << std::endl;

    switch (channel) {
        case Channel::Red:   return 0;
        case Channel::Green: return 1;
        case Channel::Blue:  return 2;
    }
}

static_assert(sizeof(Channel) == sizeof(char), "");
```

The program above prints `Red`, as you would expect. There is a degree of type safety, since you can't create an enum without initializing it, and deleting one of the cases from the `switch` will result in a warning from the compiler (depending on your compiler and flags). Also, note that `"Red"` was converted to an enum during compilation.

Comment: Heya @mrhthepie, sorry that your edit got rejected. I just saw the email about it. I'm going to incorporate it into the answer – thanks for the bugfix!

Comment: this is great. Would this also work if I want an enum of bits? Like I want an enum of BitFlags, each one is `1U` shifted over by some amount?

Comment: can you elaborate how you got it to work with bitflags?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How to use it for bit flags, or how the internals support such usage? The usage is `ENUM(Foo, uint32_t, A = 1 << 0, B = 1 << 1, C = 1 << 2)`. The internals support this because the macro uses a regular `enum` internally to declare the constants (see the answer text and code).

Comment: there seems to be a memory leak in `_trimmed_names()` in the code you posted here (`new char[length + 1]` but you don't set `initialized` to true). am I missing something? i don't see the same problem in your github code.

Comment: It is set to `true`, but outside the `if` branch (memory leak originally caught by @mrhthepie). Should move it inside... Editing. Thanks for the close look at both this and the GH code.

Comment: I'm getting compilation error if I use the `ENUM` class as a parameter in a converting constructor for another class, and try to overload the `operator<<` for that class. E.g.   `ENUM(Foo, char, A = 1,
        B
)  `  and then `class Bar
{
public:
    Bar() {}
    Bar (Foo v)
    {}
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const Bar& o  )
{
    return out;
}`, and then in my `main()`, I do this `Foo f = Foo:A; cout << f << endl; ` It complains about ambiguous overload of `operator<<`. Why is it doing that?

Comment: @user3240688  I just test version 0.11.1 on MSVC 2013 and mingw 4.8.2  both passed your code snippet(a typo? Foo::A).

Comment: I've tested the 0.11.1 version, and found something to improve:
* A naked c++ enum declaration / definition can appear inside class definition and function body, better enum do not allow this(due to namespace?)
* An empty enum is allowed in C++ :  enum X {};  but better enum will cause long compiler error.
* Use of on-demand static variable initialization within a function have potential race condition in multi thread environment.

Comment: `to_string` could return a `string_view` from C++17, which does not require null termination, and become constexpr.

Comment: To me it's not clear what the difference is between you ENUM and your BETTER_ENUM library. For one, it seems i cannot compare BETTER_ENUM (so create one, and then compare it to one of it's predefined values fails with some weird compile error). For two, ENUM is only implemented for up to 8 values (and BETTER_ENUM is much more).

Comment: Can you update this answer now that C++17 has been released? Specifically, you refer to certain proposals which may or may not have made it into the final version.

Comment: @einpoklum I don't have the time to do a good job researching that right now. If you or someone else proposes an edit, I can check it much faster and accept it.

Answer (score 92):

For <strike>C++17</strike> C++20, you will be interested in the work of the Reflection Study Group (SG7). There is a parallel series of papers covering **wording** ([P0194](http://wg21.link/p0194)) and **rationale, design and evolution** ([P0385](http://wg21.link/p0385)). (Links resolve to the latest paper in each series.)

As of P0194r2 (2016-10-15), the syntax would use the proposed `reflexpr` keyword:

```
meta::get_base_name_v<
  meta::get_element_m<
    meta::get_enumerators_m<reflexpr(MyEnum)>,
    0>
  >
```

For example (adapted from [Matus Choclik's reflexpr branch of clang](https://github.com/matus-chochlik/clang/blob/df25b4ced722ff85064fb464306602436d4f105d/examples/reflection/test03.cpp)):

```
#include <reflexpr>
#include <iostream>

enum MyEnum { AAA = 1, BBB, CCC = 99 };

int main()
{
  auto name_of_MyEnum_0 = 
    std::meta::get_base_name_v<
      std::meta::get_element_m<
        std::meta::get_enumerators_m<reflexpr(MyEnum)>,
        0>
    >;

  // prints "AAA"
  std::cout << name_of_MyEnum_0 << std::endl;
}
```

Static reflection failed to make it into C++17 (rather, into the probably-final draft presented at the November 2016 standards meeting in Issaquah) but there is confidence that it will make it into C++20; from [Herb Sutter's trip report](https://herbsutter.com/2016/11/15/trip-report-fall-iso-c-standards-meeting-issaquah/):

> In particular, the **Reflection** study group reviewed the latest merged static reflection proposal and found it ready to enter the main Evolution groups at our next meeting to start considering the unified static reflection proposal for a TS or for the next standard.

Comment: @antron sorry your edit got rejected; I'd have approved it if I'd seen it in time. I hadn't seen N4428 so thanks for giving the heads up.

Comment: No problem, thanks for incorporating it. I kind of wonder why it got rejected. I see the "doesn't make it more accurate" boilerplate reason, but it's clearly more accurate for the present day.

Comment: Thanks :-)  I have split the final example to avoid the horizontal scroll bar. What a pity the value `MyEnum::AAA` cannot be passed as second argument of `std::meta::get_enumerators_m` :-/

Comment: The fact that such a conceptually simple task requires 3 levels of nested template arguments is very overengineered. I'm sure there's specific, technical reasons for it. But that doesn't mean the end result is user friendly. I love C++ and the code makes sense to me. But 90% of other programmers I work with on a daily basis shun C++ because of code like this. I'm disappointed in not having seen any simpler more built-in solutions.

Comment: @void.pointer: Not necessarily. In languages like Java, this is essentially a one-liner. But - there's a catch: You need a millions-of-code-lines virtual machine under you. In C++, we don't have that, so we build our abstractions using what the language provides that's more simple, or more general. Those 90% of programmers should just not try to do this themselves, but rather rely on libraries written by others.

Comment: @einpoklum it doesn't require a virtual machine. The compiler can build a string mapping at compile time. The strings are the same as the name of the enumerators. Why over think this?

Comment: It seems the current estimate for inclusion of the upcoming Reflection TS in the standard is **C++23**:

https://herbsutter.com/2018/04/02/trip-report-winter-iso-c-standards-meeting-jacksonville/

Comment: @einpoklum The compiler already auto generates default constructors and destructors, why not auto-generate a `ostream operator<<(ostream, THING)` whenever it sees something like `std::cout << std::meta(classInstance)` or `std::meta(enumvalue)`

Comment: @void.pointer Thanks for standing up to tell that the emperor has no clothes. :) (As to the "I love C++" statement, I take it as a nice defensive declaration against potential fanboyism (fortunately not prevalent here), but if taken seriously, just for fun, it'd feel like a strange kind of affection, like: "I love electricity". :) It's a given, it's what it is, it's useful, it's everywhere, it's complex, needs serious tools & expertise, it's fast, it can hit you hard etc. etc., but as a target of romantic attractions..., dunno. My love evaporated some 15 years ago.)

Comment: @Sz These days I'm enjoying the fantastic C# language, framework, package management, and tooling support of the .NET ecosystem. I couldn't be bothered to go back to C++ again!

Answer (score 35):

[Back in 2011 I spent a weekend fine-tuning a macro-based solution](https://github.com/StackedCrooked/stacked-crooked/blob/master/Playground/GenerateEnum/main.cpp) and ended up never using it.

My current procedure is to start Vim, copy the enumerators in an empty switch body, start a new macro, transform the first enumerator into a case statement, *move the cursor to the beginning of the next line,* stop the macro and generate the remaining case statements by running the macro on the other enumerators.

Vim macros are more fun than C++ macros.

Real-life example:

```
enum class EtherType : uint16_t
{
    ARP   = 0x0806,
    IPv4  = 0x0800,
    VLAN  = 0x8100,
    IPv6  = 0x86DD
};
```

I will create this:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, EtherType ethertype)
{
    switch (ethertype)
    {
        case EtherType::ARP : return os << "ARP" ;
        case EtherType::IPv4: return os << "IPv4";
        case EtherType::VLAN: return os << "VLAN";
        case EtherType::IPv6: return os << "IPv6";
        // omit default case to trigger compiler warning for missing cases
    };
    return os << static_cast<std::uint16_t>(ethertype);
}
```

And that's how I get by.

Native support for enum stringification would be much better though. I'm very interested to see the results of the reflection workgroup in C++17.

An alternative way to do it was posted by @sehe in the [comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQUqU.gif).

Comment: I do exactly this. Although I usually use Surround vim and block selections along the way

Comment: @sehe Interesting. I should have a look at "surround" because I require way to many keystrokes currently.

Comment: Here it is in full gory, no macros (unless `.` counts): http://i.imgur.com/gY4ZhBE.gif

Comment: The animated gif is cute, but it's difficult to tell when it starts and ends, and how far in we're at. ... actually, scratch that, it's not cute, it's distracting. I say kill it.

Comment: This block-selection approach in vim is nice and all, but why not simply use something like `:'<,'>s/ *\(.*\)=.*/case EtherType::\1: return os << "\1";/`?

Answer (score 30):

This is similar to Yuri Finkelstein; but does not required boost. I am using a map so you can assign any value to the enums, any order.

Declaration of enum class as:

```
DECLARE_ENUM_WITH_TYPE(TestEnumClass, int32_t, ZERO = 0x00, TWO = 0x02, ONE = 0x01, THREE = 0x03, FOUR);
```

The following code will automatically create the enum class and overload:

- '+' '+=' for std::string
- '<<' for streams
- '~' just to convert to string (Any unary operator will do, but I personally don't like it for clarity)
- '*' to get the count of enums

No boost required, all required functions provided.

Code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define STRING_REMOVE_CHAR(str, ch) str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ch), str.end())

std::vector<std::string> splitString(std::string str, char sep = ',') {
    std::vector<std::string> vecString;
    std::string item;

    std::stringstream stringStream(str);

    while (std::getline(stringStream, item, sep))
    {
        vecString.push_back(item);
    }

    return vecString;
}

#define DECLARE_ENUM_WITH_TYPE(E, T, ...)                                                                     \
    enum class E : T                                                                                          \
    {                                                                                                         \
        __VA_ARGS__                                                                                           \
    };                                                                                                        \
    std::map<T, std::string> E##MapName(generateEnumMap<T>(#__VA_ARGS__));                                    \
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, E enumTmp)                                                     \
    {                                                                                                         \
        os << E##MapName[static_cast<T>(enumTmp)];                                                            \
        return os;                                                                                            \
    }                                                                                                         \
    size_t operator*(E enumTmp) { (void) enumTmp; return E##MapName.size(); }                                 \
    std::string operator~(E enumTmp) { return E##MapName[static_cast<T>(enumTmp)]; }                          \
    std::string operator+(std::string &&str, E enumTmp) { return str + E##MapName[static_cast<T>(enumTmp)]; } \
    std::string operator+(E enumTmp, std::string &&str) { return E##MapName[static_cast<T>(enumTmp)] + str; } \
    std::string &operator+=(std::string &str, E enumTmp)                                                      \
    {                                                                                                         \
        str += E##MapName[static_cast<T>(enumTmp)];                                                           \
        return str;                                                                                           \
    }                                                                                                         \
    E operator++(E &enumTmp)                                                                                  \
    {                                                                                                         \
        auto iter = E##MapName.find(static_cast<T>(enumTmp));                                                 \
        if (iter == E##MapName.end() || std::next(iter) == E##MapName.end())                                  \
            iter = E##MapName.begin();                                                                        \
        else                                                                                                  \
        {                                                                                                     \
            ++iter;                                                                                           \
        }                                                                                                     \
        enumTmp = static_cast<E>(iter->first);                                                                \
        return enumTmp;                                                                                       \
    }                                                                                                         \
    bool valid##E(T value) { return (E##MapName.find(value) != E##MapName.end()); }

#define DECLARE_ENUM(E, ...) DECLARE_ENUM_WITH_TYPE(E, int32_t, __VA_ARGS__)
template <typename T>
std::map<T, std::string> generateEnumMap(std::string strMap)
{
    STRING_REMOVE_CHAR(strMap, ' ');
    STRING_REMOVE_CHAR(strMap, '(');

    std::vector<std::string> enumTokens(splitString(strMap));
    std::map<T, std::string> retMap;
    T inxMap;

    inxMap = 0;
    for (auto iter = enumTokens.begin(); iter != enumTokens.end(); ++iter)
    {
        // Token: [EnumName | EnumName=EnumValue]
        std::string enumName;
        T enumValue;
        if (iter->find('=') == std::string::npos)
        {
            enumName = *iter;
        }
        else
        {
            std::vector<std::string> enumNameValue(splitString(*iter, '='));
            enumName = enumNameValue[0];
            //inxMap = static_cast<T>(enumNameValue[1]);
            if (std::is_unsigned<T>::value)
            {
                inxMap = static_cast<T>(std::stoull(enumNameValue[1], 0, 0));
            }
            else
            {
                inxMap = static_cast<T>(std::stoll(enumNameValue[1], 0, 0));
            }
        }
        retMap[inxMap++] = enumName;
    }

    return retMap;
}
```

Example:

```
DECLARE_ENUM_WITH_TYPE(TestEnumClass, int32_t, ZERO = 0x00, TWO = 0x02, ONE = 0x01, THREE = 0x03, FOUR);

int main(void) {
    TestEnumClass first, second;
    first = TestEnumClass::FOUR;
    second = TestEnumClass::TWO;

    std::cout << first << "(" << static_cast<uint32_t>(first) << ")" << std::endl; // FOUR(4)

    std::string strOne;
    strOne = ~first;
    std::cout << strOne << std::endl; // FOUR

    std::string strTwo;
    strTwo = ("Enum-" + second) + (TestEnumClass::THREE + "-test");
    std::cout << strTwo << std::endl; // Enum-TWOTHREE-test

    std::string strThree("TestEnumClass: ");
    strThree += second;
    std::cout << strThree << std::endl; // TestEnumClass: TWO
    std::cout << "Enum count=" << *first << std::endl;
}
```

<kbd>You can run the code [here](http://jdoodle.com/a/w1Q)</kbd>

Comment: Can we have line breaks inside this macro definition?

Comment: Added line breaks inside this macro definition as requested.

Comment: +1. Love your solution. The most compact version and it works. Even for my purpose I could minimize it because I don't need the `std::string` overloads.

Comment: I added the overload for `*` to get the count of enums... I hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: Is there any reason this implementation uses `std::map` (O(log(n)) indexing) rather than `std::unordered_map` (O(1) indexing)?

Comment: also, I think the methods should be marked `inline` so you can declared enums in header files like normal without getting "multiple definition of" errors from the linker. (not sure if that's actually the cleanest/best solution, though)

Comment: (sorry to spam but I can't seem to edit comments today) there are other issues with this being in a header file. The map (`E##MapName`) needs to be moved to a compilation unit which has access to the enum as well. I've created a solution, but it's not very clean and I'd have to get permission to share it. For now, I'm just commenting to say there's no point in marking the methods inline without the additional features necessary to support usage in a header file.

Comment: I'm not completely sold by the choice of `+` (it feels wrong alongside a lack of, say, `op+(string, int)`) but I don't know what else to suggest. Perhaps stick with a `ToString` free function?

Comment: This solution deosn't support having `constexpr` expressions as values for the enums.

Answer (score 23):

I don't know if you're going to like this or not, I'm not pretty happy with this solution but it is a C++14 friendly approach because it is using template variables and abusing template specialization:

```
enum class MyEnum : std::uint_fast8_t {
   AAA,
   BBB,
   CCC,
};

template<MyEnum> const char MyEnumName[] = "Invalid MyEnum value";
template<> const char MyEnumName<MyEnum::AAA>[] = "AAA";
template<> const char MyEnumName<MyEnum::BBB>[] = "BBB";
template<> const char MyEnumName<MyEnum::CCC>[] = "CCC";

int main()
{
    // Prints "AAA"
    std::cout << MyEnumName<MyEnum::AAA> << '\n';
    // Prints "Invalid MyEnum value"
    std::cout << MyEnumName<static_cast<MyEnum>(0x12345678)> << '\n';
    // Well... in fact it prints "Invalid MyEnum value" for any value
    // different of MyEnum::AAA, MyEnum::BBB or MyEnum::CCC.

    return 0;
}
```

The worst about this approach is that is a pain to maintain, but it is also a pain to maintain some of other similar aproaches, aren't they?

Good points about this aproach:

- Using variable tempates (C++14 feature)
- With template specialization we can "detect" when an invalid value is used (but I'm not sure if this could be useful at all).
- It looks neat.
- The name lookup is done at compile time.

<kbd>[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2LIbwGlD0MDD3wEi)</kbd>

#### Edit

Misterious [user673679](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673679/user673679) you're right; the C++14 variable template approach doesn't handles the runtime case, it was my fault to forget it :(

But we can still use some modern C++ features and variable template plus variadic template trickery to achieve a runtime translation from enum value to string... it is as bothersome as the others but still worth to mention.

Let's start using a template alias to shorten the access to a enum-to-string map:

```
// enum_map contains pairs of enum value and value string for each enum
// this shortcut allows us to use enum_map<whatever>.
template <typename ENUM>
using enum_map = std::map<ENUM, const std::string>;

// This variable template will create a map for each enum type which is
// instantiated with.
template <typename ENUM>
enum_map<ENUM> enum_values{};
```

Then, the variadic template trickery:

```
template <typename ENUM>
void initialize() {}

template <typename ENUM, typename ... args>
void initialize(const ENUM value, const char *name, args ... tail)
{
    enum_values<ENUM>.emplace(value, name);
    initialize<ENUM>(tail ...);
}
```

The "*best trick*" here is the use of variable template for the map which contains the values and names of each enum entry; this map will be the same in each translation unit and have the same name everywhere so is pretty straightforward and neat, if we call the `initialize` function like this:

```
initialize
(
    MyEnum::AAA, "AAA",
    MyEnum::BBB, "BBB",
    MyEnum::CCC, "CCC"
);
```

We are asigning names to each `MyEnum` entry and can be used in runtime:

```
std::cout << enum_values<MyEnum>[MyEnum::AAA] << '\n';
```

But can be improved with SFINAE and overloading `<<` operator:

```
template<typename ENUM, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<ENUM>::value>::type>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const ENUM value)
{
    static const std::string Unknown{std::string{typeid(ENUM).name()} + " unknown value"};
    auto found = enum_values<ENUM>.find(value);

    return o << (found == enum_values<ENUM>.end() ? Unknown : found->second);
}
```

With the correct `operator <<` now we can use the enum this way:

```
std::cout << MyEnum::AAA << '\n';
```

This is also bothersome to maintain and can be improved, but hope you get the idea.

<kbd>[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KkZ0H64SKsODnwzC)</kbd>

Comment: This looks quite neat (is it possible to just not define the unspecialized variable?). Maybe I'm missing something, though as I don't see how it handles the runtime case at all.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus: Shouldn't you just use an `std::array` instead of the unwieldy map? It will only become preferable for enums starting at... what, 2^10 values? Perhaps even more.

Comment: @einpoklum that would be amazing if we can ensure at runtime how many elements an `enum` have. Unfortunatelly, we cannot. And the whole point of the map is just to associate names with values, which is what `std::map` is good for.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus: You're already calling an `initialize()` function whose number of arguments is the number of enum values, so you know the number of values at compile-time. It's only the specific value you're asked to print that is known at run-time-only. Also, even if you didn't know that number, an std::vector would be faster than an std::map, again, in almost all realistic cases.

Comment: @einpoklum that's a very good point indeed, I'll think about it, thanks! The only thing that keeps me worrying is that `std::array` is not a key-value container and therefore lacks of find methods; anyways I'll give it a thought.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus: [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is your friend.

Comment: I found this question a few months later, but a reason NOT to use an array or vector would be if the enum values themselves don't start at zero.  Enums can sometimes be used for message types from binary data, so maybe their values sttart at above 2^10, even if there are only a few dozen values in the enum, because they correspond to "real values" in an embedded system or such.

Answer (score 10):

If your `enum` looks  like

```
enum MyEnum
{
  AAA = -8,
  BBB = '8',
  CCC = AAA + BBB
};
```

You can move the content of the `enum` to a new file:

```
AAA = -8,
BBB = '8',
CCC = AAA + BBB
```

And then the values can be surrounded by a macro:

```
// default definition
#ifned ITEM(X,Y)
#define ITEM(X,Y)
#endif

// Items list
ITEM(AAA,-8)
ITEM(BBB,'8')
ITEM(CCC,AAA+BBB)

// clean up
#undef ITEM
```

Next step may be include the items in the `enum` again:

```
enum MyEnum
{
  #define ITEM(X,Y) X=Y,
  #include "enum_definition_file"
};
```

And finally you can generate utility functions about this `enum`:

```
std::string ToString(MyEnum value)
{
  switch( value )
  {
    #define ITEM(X,Y) case X: return #X;
    #include "enum_definition_file"
  }

  return "";
}

MyEnum FromString(std::string const& value)
{
  static std::map<std::string,MyEnum> converter
  {
    #define ITEM(X,Y) { #X, X },
    #include "enum_definition_file"
  };

  auto it = converter.find(value);
  if( it != converter.end() )
    return it->second;
  else
    throw std::runtime_error("Value is missing");
}
```

The solution can be applied to older C++ standards and it does not use modern C++ elements but it can be used to generate lot of code without too much effort and maintenance.

Comment: There is no need for a separate file. This is essentially an [x-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if you split the solution in some files you can reuse the enum values for different purposes

Comment: I'm trying to you say that you can do the same thing if you put the list of values into a single macro alongside the enum definition in a header.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes i understand you but i prefer this solution. on the other hand this solution can be found in clang source code so i think it is a good way to solve the problem

Comment: Fair enough. Shouldn't have downvoted this I guess, since it can indeed have some uses. (Pardon the dummy edit, the system locks my vote otherwise.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat don't worry... Thanks for reading the answer and giving your opinion

Comment: In clang the definitions are in a separate source file because they are autogenerated by the tablegen tool.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem a couple of days ago. I couldn't find any C++ solution without some weird macro magic, so I decided to write [a CMake code generator](https://github.com/mensinda/cmakeBuildTools/blob/master/enum2string.cmake) to generate simple switch case statements.

Usage:

```
enum2str_generate(
  PATH          <path to place the files in>
  CLASS_NAME    <name of the class (also prefix for the files)>
  FUNC_NAME     <name of the (static) member function>
  NAMESPACE     <the class will be inside this namespace>
  INCLUDES      <LIST of files where the enums are defined>
  ENUMS         <LIST of enums to process>
  BLACKLIST     <LIST of constants to ignore>
  USE_CONSTEXPR <whether to use constexpr or not (default: off)>
  USE_C_STRINGS <whether to use c strings instead of std::string or not (default: off)>
)
```

The function searches the include files in the filesystem (uses the include directories provided with the include_directories command), reads them and does some regex to generate the class and the function(s).

NOTE: constexpr implies inline in C++, so using the USE_CONSTEXPR option will generate a header only class!

Example:

./includes/a.h:

```
enum AAA : char { A1, A2 };

typedef enum {
   VAL1          = 0,
   VAL2          = 1,
   VAL3          = 2,
   VAL_FIRST     = VAL1,    // Ignored
   VAL_LAST      = VAL3,    // Ignored
   VAL_DUPLICATE = 1,       // Ignored
   VAL_STRANGE   = VAL2 + 1 // Must be blacklisted
} BBB;
```

./CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes ...)

enum2str_generate(
   PATH       "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"
   CLASS_NAME "enum2Str"
   NAMESPACE  "abc"
   FUNC_NAME  "toStr"
   INCLUDES   "a.h" # WITHOUT directory
   ENUMS      "AAA" "BBB"
   BLACKLIST  "VAL_STRANGE")
```

Generates:

./enum2Str.hpp:

```
/*!
  * \file enum2Str.hpp
  * \warning This is an automatically generated file!
  */

#ifndef ENUM2STR_HPP
#define ENUM2STR_HPP

#include <string>
#include <a.h>

namespace abc {

class enum2Str {
 public:
   static std::string toStr( AAA _var ) noexcept;
   static std::string toStr( BBB _var ) noexcept;
};

}

#endif // ENUM2STR_HPP
```

./enum2Str.cpp:

```
/*!
  * \file enum2Str.cpp
  * \warning This is an automatically generated file!
  */

#include "enum2Str.hpp"

namespace abc {

/*!
 * \brief Converts the enum AAA to a std::string
 * \param _var The enum value to convert
 * \returns _var converted to a std::string
 */
std::string enum2Str::toStr( AAA _var ) noexcept {
   switch ( _var ) {
      case A1: return "A1";
      case A2: return "A2";
      default: return "<UNKNOWN>";
   }
}

/*!
 * \brief Converts the enum BBB to a std::string
 * \param _var The enum value to convert
 * \returns _var converted to a std::string
 */
std::string enum2Str::toStr( BBB _var ) noexcept {
   switch ( _var ) {
      case VAL1: return "VAL1";
      case VAL2: return "VAL2";
      case VAL3: return "VAL3";
      default: return "<UNKNOWN>";
   }
}
}
```

## Update:

The script now also supports scoped enumerations (enum class|struct) and
I moved it to a seperate repo with some other scripts I often use: https://github.com/mensinda/cmakeBuildTools

Comment: wow! Very original and innovative idea :-) I hope you have the courage to upgrade your generator in order to provide a `constexpr` and `noexcept` version ;-) I have also just stared [your GitHub project](https://github.com/EEnginE/engine/blob/vulkan/cmake/enum2string.cmake) ;-) Cheers

Comment: Updated the generator. The functions will now be always constexpr and enum : <type> is now supported.
Thanks for the star :)

Comment: The link is broken... -.-

Comment: The link is now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

As per request from the OP, here a stripped down version of the ugly macro solution based on [Boost Preprosessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor) and [Variadic Macros](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/variadic_macros.html).

It allows for a simple list like syntax of the enumerator elements along with setting values for specific elements so that

```
XXX_ENUM(foo,(a,b,(c,42)));
```

expands to

```
enum foo {
    a,
    b,
    c=42
};
```

Alongside with the necessary functions to output and do some conversion back. This macro has been around here for ages, and I am not totally sure that its the most efficient way, or that it is a conforming way, but it has ever since been working

The complete code can be seen in action at both [Ideone](http://ideone.com/dkh47G) and [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88db49bdeacdb654).

Its gargantuan ugliness is above; I would have put it behind spoilers to protect your eyes, if I knew how, but markdown doesn't like me.

#### The library (merged within one single header file)

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace xxx
{

template<class T>
struct enum_cast_adl_helper { };

template<class E>
E enum_cast( const std::string& s )
{
    return do_enum_cast(s,enum_cast_adl_helper<E>());
}

template<class E>
E enum_cast( const char* cs )
{
    std::string s(cs);
    return enum_cast<E>(s);
}

} // namespace xxx

#define XXX_PP_ARG_N(                             \
          _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9,_10, \
         _11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20, \
         _21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30, \
         _31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40, \
         _41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50, \
         _51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60, \
         _61,_62,_63,N,...) N

#define XXX_PP_RSEQ_N()                 \
         63,62,61,60,                   \
         59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50, \
         49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40, \
         39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30, \
         29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20, \
         19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10, \
         9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 

#define XXX_PP_NARG_(...) XXX_PP_ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__)
#define XXX_PP_NARG(...)  XXX_PP_NARG_(__VA_ARGS__,XXX_PP_RSEQ_N())
#define XXX_TUPLE_SIZE_INTERNAL(TUPLE) XXX_PP_NARG TUPLE

#define XXX_TUPLE_CHOICE(i)                            \
  BOOST_PP_APPLY(                                      \
    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(                               \
      25, i, (                                         \
        (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8),   \
        (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), \
        (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23), (24) \
  ) ) )

#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_00  BOOST_PP_BOOL_0
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_01  BOOST_PP_BOOL_1
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_02  BOOST_PP_BOOL_2
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_03  BOOST_PP_BOOL_3
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_04  BOOST_PP_BOOL_4
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_05  BOOST_PP_BOOL_5
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_06  BOOST_PP_BOOL_6
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_07  BOOST_PP_BOOL_7
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_08  BOOST_PP_BOOL_8
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_09  BOOST_PP_BOOL_9
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_010 BOOST_PP_BOOL_10
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_011 BOOST_PP_BOOL_11
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_012 BOOST_PP_BOOL_12
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_013 BOOST_PP_BOOL_13
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_014 BOOST_PP_BOOL_14
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_015 BOOST_PP_BOOL_15
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_016 BOOST_PP_BOOL_16
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_017 BOOST_PP_BOOL_17
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_018 BOOST_PP_BOOL_18
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_019 BOOST_PP_BOOL_19
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_020 BOOST_PP_BOOL_20
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_021 BOOST_PP_BOOL_21
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_022 BOOST_PP_BOOL_22
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_023 BOOST_PP_BOOL_23
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_024 BOOST_PP_BOOL_24
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_025 BOOST_PP_BOOL_25
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_026 BOOST_PP_BOOL_26
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_027 BOOST_PP_BOOL_27
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_028 BOOST_PP_BOOL_28
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_029 BOOST_PP_BOOL_29
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_030 BOOST_PP_BOOL_30
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_031 BOOST_PP_BOOL_31
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_032 BOOST_PP_BOOL_32
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_033 BOOST_PP_BOOL_33
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_034 BOOST_PP_BOOL_34
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_035 BOOST_PP_BOOL_35
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_036 BOOST_PP_BOOL_36
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_037 BOOST_PP_BOOL_37
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_038 BOOST_PP_BOOL_38
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_039 BOOST_PP_BOOL_39
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_040 BOOST_PP_BOOL_40
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_041 BOOST_PP_BOOL_41
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_042 BOOST_PP_BOOL_42
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_043 BOOST_PP_BOOL_43
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_044 BOOST_PP_BOOL_44
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_045 BOOST_PP_BOOL_45
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_046 BOOST_PP_BOOL_46
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_047 BOOST_PP_BOOL_47
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_048 BOOST_PP_BOOL_48
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_049 BOOST_PP_BOOL_49
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_050 BOOST_PP_BOOL_50
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_051 BOOST_PP_BOOL_51
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_052 BOOST_PP_BOOL_52
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_053 BOOST_PP_BOOL_53
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_054 BOOST_PP_BOOL_54
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_055 BOOST_PP_BOOL_55
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_056 BOOST_PP_BOOL_56
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_057 BOOST_PP_BOOL_57
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_058 BOOST_PP_BOOL_58
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_059 BOOST_PP_BOOL_59
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_060 BOOST_PP_BOOL_60
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_061 BOOST_PP_BOOL_61
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_062 BOOST_PP_BOOL_62
#define BOOST_PP_BOOL_063 BOOST_PP_BOOL_63

#define BOOST_PP_DEC_00  BOOST_PP_DEC_0
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_01  BOOST_PP_DEC_1
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_02  BOOST_PP_DEC_2
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_03  BOOST_PP_DEC_3
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_04  BOOST_PP_DEC_4
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_05  BOOST_PP_DEC_5
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_06  BOOST_PP_DEC_6
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_07  BOOST_PP_DEC_7
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_08  BOOST_PP_DEC_8
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_09  BOOST_PP_DEC_9
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_010 BOOST_PP_DEC_10
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_011 BOOST_PP_DEC_11
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_012 BOOST_PP_DEC_12
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_013 BOOST_PP_DEC_13
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_014 BOOST_PP_DEC_14
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_015 BOOST_PP_DEC_15
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_016 BOOST_PP_DEC_16
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_017 BOOST_PP_DEC_17
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_018 BOOST_PP_DEC_18
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_019 BOOST_PP_DEC_19
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_020 BOOST_PP_DEC_20
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_021 BOOST_PP_DEC_21
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_022 BOOST_PP_DEC_22
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_023 BOOST_PP_DEC_23
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_024 BOOST_PP_DEC_24
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_025 BOOST_PP_DEC_25
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_026 BOOST_PP_DEC_26
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_027 BOOST_PP_DEC_27
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_028 BOOST_PP_DEC_28
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_029 BOOST_PP_DEC_29
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_030 BOOST_PP_DEC_30
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_031 BOOST_PP_DEC_31
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_032 BOOST_PP_DEC_32
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_033 BOOST_PP_DEC_33
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_034 BOOST_PP_DEC_34
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_035 BOOST_PP_DEC_35
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_036 BOOST_PP_DEC_36
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_037 BOOST_PP_DEC_37
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_038 BOOST_PP_DEC_38
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_039 BOOST_PP_DEC_39
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_040 BOOST_PP_DEC_40
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_041 BOOST_PP_DEC_41
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_042 BOOST_PP_DEC_42
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_043 BOOST_PP_DEC_43
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_044 BOOST_PP_DEC_44
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_045 BOOST_PP_DEC_45
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_046 BOOST_PP_DEC_46
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_047 BOOST_PP_DEC_47
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_048 BOOST_PP_DEC_48
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_049 BOOST_PP_DEC_49
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_050 BOOST_PP_DEC_50
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_051 BOOST_PP_DEC_51
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_052 BOOST_PP_DEC_52
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_053 BOOST_PP_DEC_53
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_054 BOOST_PP_DEC_54
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_055 BOOST_PP_DEC_55
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_056 BOOST_PP_DEC_56
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_057 BOOST_PP_DEC_57
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_058 BOOST_PP_DEC_58
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_059 BOOST_PP_DEC_59
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_060 BOOST_PP_DEC_60
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_061 BOOST_PP_DEC_61
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_062 BOOST_PP_DEC_62
#define BOOST_PP_DEC_063 BOOST_PP_DEC_63

#define XXX_TO_NUMx(x) 0 ## x
#define XXX_TO_NUM(x) BOOST_PP_ADD(0,XXX_TO_NUMx(x))
#define XXX_STRINGIZEX(x) # x
#define XXX_VSTRINGIZE_SINGLE(a,b,x) XXX_STRINGIZE(x)
#define XXX_VSTRINGIZE_TUPLE(tpl) XXX_TUPLE_FOR_EACH(XXX_VSTRINGIZE_SINGLE,,tpl)
#define XXX_TUPLE_SIZE(TUPLE) XXX_TO_NUM(XXX_TUPLE_CHOICE(XXX_TUPLE_SIZE_INTERNAL(TUPLE)))
#define XXX_TUPLE_FOR_EACH(MACRO,DATA,TUPLE) BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH(MACRO,DATA,BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_LIST(XXX_TUPLE_SIZE(TUPLE),TUPLE))
#define XXX_STRINGIZE(x) XXX_STRINGIZEX(x)
#define XXX_VSTRINGIZE(...) XXX_VSTRINGIZE_TUPLE((__VA_ARGS__))
#define XXX_CAST_TO_VOID_ELEMENT(r,data,elem) (void)(elem);
#define XXX_CAST_TO_VOID_INTERNAL(TUPLE) XXX_TUPLE_FOR_EACH(XXX_CAST_TO_VOID_ELEMENT,,TUPLE)    
#define XXX_CAST_TO_VOID(...) XXX_CAST_TO_VOID_INTERNAL((__VA_ARGS__))
#define XXX_ENUM_EXTRACT_SP(en) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(XXX_TUPLE_SIZE(en),0,en) = BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(XXX_TUPLE_SIZE(en),1,en)
#define XXX_ENUM_ELEMENT(r,data,elem) BOOST_PP_IF( XXX_TUPLE_SIZE(elem), XXX_ENUM_EXTRACT_SP(elem), elem) ,
#define XXX_ENUM_EXTRACT_ELEMENT(en) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(XXX_TUPLE_SIZE(en),0,en)
#define XXX_ENUM_CASE_ELEMENT(en) BOOST_PP_IF( XXX_TUPLE_SIZE(en), XXX_ENUM_EXTRACT_ELEMENT(en), en )
#define XXX_ENUM_CASE(r,data,elem) case data :: XXX_ENUM_CASE_ELEMENT(elem) : return #data "::" XXX_STRINGIZE(XXX_ENUM_CASE_ELEMENT(elem));
#define XXX_ENUM_IFELSE(r,data,elem) else if( en == data :: XXX_ENUM_CASE_ELEMENT(elem)) { return #data "::" XXX_STRINGIZE(XXX_ENUM_CASE_ELEMENT(elem)); }
#define XXX_ENUM_CASTLIST(r,data,elem) { XXX_STRINGIZE(XXX_ENUM_CASE_ELEMENT(elem)), data :: XXX_ENUM_CASE_ELEMENT(elem) },
#define XXX_ENUM_QUALIFIED_CASTLIST(r,data,elem) { #data "::" XXX_STRINGIZE(XXX_ENUM_CASE_ELEMENT(elem)), data :: XXX_ENUM_CASE_ELEMENT(elem) },

#define XXX_ENUM_INTERNAL(TYPE,NAME,TUPLE)                       \
enum TYPE                                                        \
{                                                                \
   XXX_TUPLE_FOR_EACH(XXX_ENUM_ELEMENT,,TUPLE)                   \
   BOOST_PP_CAT(last_enum_,NAME)                                 \
};                                                               \
                                                                 \
inline                                                           \
const char* to_string( NAME en )                                 \
{                                                                \
   if(false)                                                     \
   {                                                             \
   }                                                             \
   XXX_TUPLE_FOR_EACH(XXX_ENUM_IFELSE,NAME,TUPLE)                \
   else if( en == NAME :: BOOST_PP_CAT(last_enum_,NAME) )        \
   {                                                             \
     return XXX_VSTRINGIZE(NAME,::,BOOST_PP_CAT(last_enum_,NAME));  \
   }                                                             \
   else                                                          \
   {                                                             \
     return "Invalid enum value specified for " # NAME;          \
   }                                                             \
}                                                                \
                                                                 \
inline                                                           \
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const NAME& en )     \
{                                                                \
   os << to_string(en);                                          \
   return os;                                                    \
}                                                                \
                                                                 \
inline                                                           \
NAME do_enum_cast( const std::string& s, const ::xxx::enum_cast_adl_helper<NAME>& ) \
{                                                                \
  static const std::unordered_map<std::string,NAME> map =        \
  {                                                              \
    XXX_TUPLE_FOR_EACH(XXX_ENUM_CASTLIST,NAME,TUPLE)             \
    XXX_TUPLE_FOR_EACH(XXX_ENUM_QUALIFIED_CASTLIST,NAME,TUPLE)   \
  };                                                             \
                                                                 \
  auto cit = map.find(s);                                        \
  if( cit == map.end() )                                         \
  {                                                              \
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid value to cast to enum");   \
  }                                                              \
  return cit->second;                                            \
}

#define XXX_ENUM(NAME,TUPLE) XXX_ENUM_INTERNAL(NAME,NAME,TUPLE)
#define XXX_ENUM_CLASS(NAME,TUPLE) XXX_ENUM_INTERNAL(class NAME,NAME,TUPLE)
#define XXX_ENUM_CLASS_TYPE(NAME,TYPE,TUPLE) XXX_ENUM_INTERNAL(class NAME : TYPE,NAME,TUPLE)
#define XXX_ENUM_TYPE(NAME,TYPE,TUPLE) XXX_ENUM_INTERNAL(NAME : TYPE,NAME,TUPLE)
```

#### Usage

```
#include "xxx_enum.h"  // the above lib
#include <iostream>

XXX_ENUM(foo,(a,b,(c,42)));

int main()
{
  std::cout << "foo::a = "            << foo::a            <<'\n';
  std::cout << "(int)foo::c = "       << (int)foo::c       <<'\n';
  std::cout << "to_string(foo::b) = " << to_string(foo::b) <<'\n';
  std::cout << "xxx::enum_cast<foo>(\"b\") = " << xxx::enum_cast<foo>("b") <<'\n';
}
```

#### Compilation (copy paste header within `main.cpp`)

```
> g++ --version | sed 1q
g++ (GCC) 4.9.2

> g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra main.cpp
main.cpp:268:31: warning: extra ';' [-Wpedantic]
     XXX_ENUM(foo,(a,b,(c,42)));
                               ^
```

#### Output

```
foo::a = foo::a
(int)foo::c = 42
to_string(foo::b) = foo::b
xxx::enum_cast<foo>("b") = foo::b
```

Comment: This code block is a crazy journey through the amazing landscapes of metaprogramming black magic. I actually felt relieved upon reaching `main` — Home, sweet home !

Comment: Just added a link to coliru to check output (there are some warnings, click on the link within your answer). I have also split into Lib/Usage. Does the stuff `namespace xxx` can be moved to the header place? You can say in the intro your use `boost/preprocessor.hpp` and therefore the answer *is modern C++ compliant*. Please fix the warnings and clean a bit the source code for better quality.

Comment: @olibre: It is copypastad from I think 5 different headers in our library. The enum_cast is from another more general part but I thought to add it too to see what the do_enum_cast in the macro is for.. The warnings is just from my `main<tab>` of vim including args I do not use. I dont think this code can be really cleaned, it is just to show what can be done and should not be ;) and if I change it here it isnt the code I use in production anymore...it is one of those fragile things that once it works you better never touch since it might collapse in ways no one could predict.

Comment: All right Plasma, I see this can be seen as a *Proof Of Concept*. But there is too much macro overhead to be up-voted. Nevertheless thanks for sharing. Cheers

Comment: Hi Plasma. I have performed a deep source code cleaning + completed by compilation and run output. Please check [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28838042/revisions). I hope this is OK for you. Is the answer more valuable? However, the macro overhead is still horrible! Have a nice day :-) Cheers

Comment: @olibre: I think it can't be done without horrible overhead, but if it is in different layers of one library it can be handled. I think thats what libraries are for, hide the horrible stuff. Ever tried reading boost code? especially the mpl part before C++11 ...

Comment: Yes you are right, I agree. Have a look at the [Matthieu's answer also based on Boost Preprocessor but using less macro overhead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10177840/938111). OK, his solution provides less services than your lib... Cheers

Comment: @olibre: yes, getting the x=y part nicely was a major hurdle. Also I was preferring the (a,b,c) syntax instead of (a)(b)(c) for having things look more like real enum lists. Both dramatically increased the need for magic.

Comment: The abysmal readability of macro magic of this level is why I prefer source code generation so much. The macro böack magic feels so much smarter until people don't get it and start asking you to fix their mysterious compiler errors they get from holding it wrong. Or until people get stuck whle debugging an unrelated error in code using the macro.

Comment: @yeoman: both have their pros and cons. if you feed such a macro just a list of enums, adding one becomes as simple as adding it to the macro argument list. In case of code creation you would probably have to add it at a special place and run a special tool.

Comment: @PlasmaHH that is absolutely accurate 

Comment: Except that the special tool can be easily integrated in a make / cmake &c. build before anything else so it works even in the face of unrelated compiler errors 

Comment: @yeoman: as I said, all pros and cons. I would for example not want a "header only library" to come with a set of tools that I have to run in addition to compilation.

Answer (score 4):

Just generate your enums. Writing a generator for that purpose is about five minutes' work.

Generator code in java and python, super easy to port to any language you like, including C++.

Also super easy to extend by whatever functionality you want.

example input:

```
First = 5
Second
Third = 7
Fourth
Fifth=11
```

generated header:

```
#include <iosfwd>

enum class Hallo
{
    First = 5,
    Second = 6,
    Third = 7,
    Fourth = 8,
    Fifth = 11
};

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &, const Hallo&);
```

generated cpp file

```
#include <ostream>

#include "Hallo.h"

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &out, const Hallo&value)
{
    switch(value)
    {
    case Hallo::First:
        out << "First";
        break;
    case Hallo::Second:
        out << "Second";
        break;
    case Hallo::Third:
        out << "Third";
        break;
    case Hallo::Fourth:
        out << "Fourth";
        break;
    case Hallo::Fifth:
        out << "Fifth";
        break;
    default:
        out << "<unknown>";
    }

    return out;
}
```

And the generator, in a very terse form as a template for porting and extension. This example code really tries to avoid overwriting any files but still use it at your own risk.

```
package cppgen;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class EnumGenerator
{
    static void fail(String message)
    {
        System.err.println(message);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    static void run(String[] args)
    throws Exception
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\w+)\\s*(?:=\\s*(\\d+))?\\s*", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF8");
        String tab = "    ";

        if (args.length != 3)
        {
            fail("Required arguments: <enum name> <input file> <output dir>");
        }

        String enumName = args[0];

        File inputFile = new File(args[1]);

        if (inputFile.isFile() == false)
        {
            fail("Not a file: [" + inputFile.getCanonicalPath() + "]");
        }

        File outputDir = new File(args[2]);

        if (outputDir.isDirectory() == false)
        {
            fail("Not a directory: [" + outputDir.getCanonicalPath() + "]");
        }

        File headerFile = new File(outputDir, enumName + ".h");
        File codeFile = new File(outputDir, enumName + ".cpp");

        for (File file : new File[] { headerFile, codeFile })
        {
            if (file.exists())
            {
                fail("Will not overwrite file [" + file.getCanonicalPath() + "]");
            }
        }

        int nextValue = 0;

        Map<String, Integer> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        try
        (
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile), charset));
        )
        {
            while (true)
            {
                String line = reader.readLine();

                if (line == null)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (line.trim().length() == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

                if (matcher.matches() == false)
                {
                    fail("Syntax error: [" + line + "]");
                }

                String fieldName = matcher.group(1);

                if (fields.containsKey(fieldName))
                {
                    fail("Double fiend name: " + fieldName);
                }

                String valueString = matcher.group(2);

                if (valueString != null)
                {
                    int value = Integer.parseInt(valueString);

                    if (value < nextValue)
                    {
                        fail("Not a monotonous progression from " + nextValue + " to " + value + " for enum field " + fieldName);
                    }

                    nextValue = value;
                }

                fields.put(fieldName, nextValue);

                ++nextValue;
            }
        }

        try
        (
            PrintWriter headerWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(headerFile), charset));
            PrintWriter codeWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(codeFile), charset));
        )
        {
            headerWriter.println();
            headerWriter.println("#include <iosfwd>");
            headerWriter.println();
            headerWriter.println("enum class " + enumName);
            headerWriter.println('{');
            boolean first = true;
            for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : fields.entrySet())
            {
                if (first == false)
                {
                    headerWriter.println(",");
                }

                headerWriter.print(tab + entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());

                first = false;
            }
            if (first == false)
            {
                headerWriter.println();
            }
            headerWriter.println("};");
            headerWriter.println();
            headerWriter.println("std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &, const " + enumName + "&);");
            headerWriter.println();

            codeWriter.println();
            codeWriter.println("#include <ostream>");
            codeWriter.println();
            codeWriter.println("#include \"" + enumName + ".h\"");
            codeWriter.println();
            codeWriter.println("std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &out, const " + enumName + "&value)");
            codeWriter.println('{');
            codeWriter.println(tab + "switch(value)");
            codeWriter.println(tab + '{');
            first = true;
            for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : fields.entrySet())
            {
                codeWriter.println(tab + "case " + enumName + "::" + entry.getKey() + ':');
                codeWriter.println(tab + tab + "out << \"" + entry.getKey() + "\";");
                codeWriter.println(tab + tab + "break;");

                first = false;
            }
            codeWriter.println(tab + "default:");
            codeWriter.println(tab + tab + "out << \"<unknown>\";");
            codeWriter.println(tab + '}');
            codeWriter.println();
            codeWriter.println(tab + "return out;");
            codeWriter.println('}');
            codeWriter.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            run(args);
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And a port to Python 3.5 because different enough to be potentially helpful

```
import re
import collections
import sys
import io
import os

def fail(*args):
    print(*args)
    exit(1)

pattern = re.compile(r'\s*(\w+)\s*(?:=\s*(\d+))?\s*')
tab = "    "

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    n=0
    for arg in sys.argv:
        print("arg", n, ":", arg, " / ", sys.argv[n])
        n += 1
    fail("Required arguments: <enum name> <input file> <output dir>")

enumName = sys.argv[1]

inputFile = sys.argv[2]

if not os.path.isfile(inputFile):
    fail("Not a file: [" + os.path.abspath(inputFile) + "]")

outputDir = sys.argv[3]

if not os.path.isdir(outputDir):
    fail("Not a directory: [" + os.path.abspath(outputDir) + "]")

headerFile = os.path.join(outputDir, enumName + ".h")
codeFile = os.path.join(outputDir, enumName + ".cpp")

for file in [ headerFile, codeFile ]:
    if os.path.exists(file):
        fail("Will not overwrite file [" + os.path.abspath(file) + "]")

nextValue = 0

fields = collections.OrderedDict()

for line in open(inputFile, 'r'):
    line = line.strip()

    if len(line) == 0:
        continue

    match = pattern.match(line)

    if match == None:
        fail("Syntax error: [" + line + "]")

    fieldName = match.group(1)

    if fieldName in fields:
        fail("Double field name: " + fieldName)

    valueString = match.group(2)

    if valueString != None:
        value = int(valueString)

        if value < nextValue:
            fail("Not a monotonous progression from " + nextValue + " to " + value + " for enum field " + fieldName)

        nextValue = value

    fields[fieldName] = nextValue

    nextValue += 1

headerWriter = open(headerFile, 'w')
codeWriter = open(codeFile, 'w')

try:
    headerWriter.write("\n")
    headerWriter.write("#include <iosfwd>\n")
    headerWriter.write("\n")
    headerWriter.write("enum class " + enumName + "\n")
    headerWriter.write("{\n")
    first = True
    for fieldName, fieldValue in fields.items():
        if not first:
            headerWriter.write(",\n")

        headerWriter.write(tab + fieldName + " = " + str(fieldValue))

        first = False
    if not first:
        headerWriter.write("\n")
    headerWriter.write("};\n")
    headerWriter.write("\n")
    headerWriter.write("std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &, const " + enumName + "&);\n")
    headerWriter.write("\n")

    codeWriter.write("\n")
    codeWriter.write("#include <ostream>\n")
    codeWriter.write("\n")
    codeWriter.write("#include \"" + enumName + ".h\"\n")
    codeWriter.write("\n")
    codeWriter.write("std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &out, const " + enumName + "&value)\n")
    codeWriter.write("{\n")
    codeWriter.write(tab + "switch(value)\n")
    codeWriter.write(tab + "{\n")
    for fieldName in fields.keys():
        codeWriter.write(tab + "case " + enumName + "::" + fieldName + ":\n")
        codeWriter.write(tab + tab + "out << \"" + fieldName + "\";\n")
        codeWriter.write(tab + tab + "break;\n")
    codeWriter.write(tab + "default:\n")
    codeWriter.write(tab + tab + "out << \"<unknown>\";\n")
    codeWriter.write(tab + "}\n")
    codeWriter.write("\n")
    codeWriter.write(tab + "return out;\n")
    codeWriter.write("}\n")
    codeWriter.write("\n")
finally:
    headerWriter.close()
    codeWriter.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your generator in two languages :-) But do you have any idea how to generate at compile-time? For instance, can we imagine translating your generator using CMake statements in order to refresh the C++ generated code when input data is changed? My dream is to force the C++ compiler to generate enums at compilation using meta-programming (`variadic template class` and `constexpr` functions).

Comment: Otoh, in case it's too cumbersome to add a custom cmake command, you can automate your IDE or call the gererator manually and have the output in source control.

It's sometimes a good idea to have generated code in source control anyway, as long it's not too much, and people understand that they're not supposed to make manual changes, because it's sometimes interesting to look at the history of the generated files when you're debugging something weird and have the suspicion that a recent change to the generator may have broken something :)

Comment: About generating things at compile time, that's so easy in LISP because the syntax is so extremely clean and easy.
That's helped by the fact that it's dynamically typed, which allows it to be terse and readable without much syntax. The equivalent of LISP macros in C++ would need a very complicated way to describe the AST of what you're trying to generate. And an AST for C++ is never pretty :(

Comment: Directly in Make instead of cmake, it's super easy btw. Just generate .h and .cpp targets for each .enum file via find, and have these targets depend on said enum defs, so they're automatically re-generated once the .enum def files change. It's probably a lot easier in cmake because it's full of magic for this kind of things but I regularly use Make, ant, and gradle, but only have limited knowledge of Maven, cmake, and grunt :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-) I think most of the C++ developers will appreciate if your generator could detect enums directly within C++ code like `enum class Hallo{ First=5, Second=6, Third=7, Fourth=8};` or in several lines :-D Do you think you can adapt your generator in order to detect an `enum` within a C++ file? The best could be to generate code only on detection of a tag like `/*<Generate enum to string here>*/`. Then your generator writes in-place the corresponding C++ generated code (replacing the previous generated code). ^_^ What an awesome generator isn't it? Cheers :-)

Comment: Replacing code in place is generally a bad idea. What if you decide to add twenty new enum fields? then this input is lost because it was overwritten. plus, when you attempt to make it SMART, leaving the input inn place and adding the generated code right beneath it, and replace your generated code by the newly generated code in case of a change on the input, you can bet that sooner or later something will go wrong and your generator deletes some code it wasn't supposed to -.-

Comment: If having a text file in your project that is not C++ source is unacceptable to you, and you get paid for your time and not for the actual work you get done, I suggest manually writing the equivalent manual enums. But don't forget to write a couple of unit tests for each one so you don't accidentally build in the typical copy & paste errors :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :-) +1 You are right, changing content of a C++ source file is not a good idea (for example, the file could be read-only). Therefore, the generated code should be somewhere with the other generated files (e.g. *.o files). Using your idea, the build tool chain (Makefile or CMake or ...) may call an external module (in Java or Python...) to detect the enums directly within the C++ code and generate the corresponding enum_to_string functions. Your code may evolve to use clang-parser in order to understand the C++ source Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)... Cheers

Comment: That adds a lot of complexity and comes at a high price. C++ code is easy to debug. An object file without real source is not -.-

Comment: Btw. what is the problem with having source files in a simple generator input language that automatically are built into generated C++ source files that are then compiled via the C++ compiler, all automatically? What is the pain point there for you? :):)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion on generated C++ and object files. I mean the generated C++ files must be written in a read/write directory. And the object files must also be written in read/write directories. Generated C++ files should not be written along the input C++ files (e.g. the directory could be read-only). My conclusion is the generated C++ files should be written  in similar directory tree as the object files. Like object files, these generated C++ files are temporaries. On my opinion, all these temporaries should be all removed on full cleanup.

Comment: Imagine two tools to generate C++. Both tools are easy to use and reliable. The difference: (1) With the first tool, the developer writes pseudo `enum` code in a configuration file and the tool generates both `enum` and `enum_to_string` function. (2) With the second tool, the developer continues to write `enum` in C++ (within the right namespace/class), and the tool generates just the corresponding `enum_to_string` function. I think most developers will prefer the second tool. I do not say the first tool has a problem. I just think the second is more comfortable. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, an extra directory for generated source files is a must :) I mostly call it "generated", and I generate a warning comment on top of every generated source file that states that it's going to be overwritten :)

Comment: If the enum is a C++ enum class, then yes, you can write it in a header file. But you still need information about the name of the generated header and source file  and the header file to read the enum from etc. in the config, so you end up with two sources, plus the resulting enum is then spread across several files, and the extra header file must be included manually because the generator won't touch any of your manual code files.

Comment: If, otoh, the enum is in fact a typesafe enum class with all kinds of potential extra functionality built in, you want all of it generated in any case because the header itself then contains a lot of boilerplate. I usually use this approach, and I also generate lots of other things like structs, connection classes &c. for several platforms (C++, Java, Python, C#, Objective-C, Swift), so I work with extra IDL files in any case, and the enums live there with everything else, and that feels quite natural to me by now :)

Comment: For C++ enums, and enums only, with extra header files for enum support functions, I think working with the llvm to get at the AST is a bad idea because not only is the llvm a really large code base but it's also a MESS. I've rarely seen less readable code than in the llvm.

Comment: Plus, there's a world beyond the llvm, and enum classes are sufficiently easy to parse with simple regex, especially with a helper comment containing all information for the genrator so there is NO extra config file (important in this case I think, because single source is always a great idea), and Python does everything, independent of the llvm, so you can even do it in Windows or in a classic gcc setup (and I really dislike using several compilers at once) :)

Comment: So in a setting with C++ enums, your idea wins, but with python, and there's no extra config file :)

Comment: Thank you Yeoman for your explanations. You are right, moreover writing a generator reading a simple text input is a lot easier than from a complex C++ input (the C++ enum may be obfuscated by a `#define MACRO`).

Comment: But using Clang AST should not be so difficult. For example, [Loïc](https://github.com/JolyLoic) has presented at C++ Paris meetup (C++FRUG) a tool to visualize the AST from a C++ code you paste in its left windows: [Clang-ast-viewer](https://github.com/CAST-projects/Clang-ast-viewer). We could imagine that the code is generated only if the function `std::string EnumX_to_string(EnumX)` is declared. The generated filename `*.cpp` is deduced from the filename where this function is declared. No need to include it. I have enjoyed our constructive discussion ;-) Cheers

Comment: :):) using clang's AST is certainly far from hard or impossible. But compared to doing *nothing at all* because I happen to have my input IDLs and parsing tools up and running, it would indeed be a monumental effort of several days' work :)

Comment: Btw. even though the code base of the llvm is a mess, it's still fascinating, and I truly recommend you have a look inside and maybe try to get your hands at the AST of an enum and try to create something from it. It'll be very insightful about how things actually work in the llvm in detail, how the sausage REALLY is made, behind the shiny facade with clang and swift and apple's marketing and the hype around it, which I found fascinating in unexpected ways, both glorious and terrifying :D

Comment: Just out of curiosity - is Loïc a Breton name? :)

Comment: As far as I think, all the _Loïc_ I know come from _Bretagne_ (or their parents). My colleagues at Paris think also _Loïc_ is a _Breton_ name. But after reading the [article Loïc on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lo%C3%AFc), I see that _Loïc_ may come from _"old Provençal form of Louis"_ or from _"Greek name Loukas"_... Next time I will meet [Loïc Joly](https://github.com/JolyLoic) I will ask him if his name is from _Bretagne_...

Answer (score 4):

You can abuse [user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) to achieve the desired result:

```
enum
{
  AAA = "AAA"_h8,
  BB = "BB"_h8,
};
   
std::cout << h8::to_string(AAA) << std::endl;
std::cout << h8::to_string(BB) << std::endl;
```

This packs a string into an integer, which is reversible. Check out the example [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZqrugpL8gPCB4yZr).

Comment: Sadly only works for strings of length <= 8

Comment: we will be at 16 chars soon.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/user1095108/h8) is the current version of h8.

Answer (score 3):

I have been frustrated by this problem for a long time too, along with the problem of getting a type converted to string in a proper way. However, for the last problem, I was surprised by the solution explained in [Is it possible to print a variable's type in standard C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c), using the idea from [Can I obtain C++ type names in a constexpr way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35941045/can-i-obtain-c-type-names-in-a-constexpr-way/35943472#35943472). Using this technique, an analogous function can be constructed for getting an enum value as string:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class static_string
{
    const char* const p_;
    const std::size_t sz_;

public:
    typedef const char* const_iterator;

    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr static_string(const char(&a)[N]) noexcept
        : p_(a)
        , sz_(N - 1)
    {}

    constexpr static_string(const char* p, std::size_t N) noexcept
        : p_(p)
        , sz_(N)
    {}

    constexpr const char* data() const noexcept { return p_; }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const noexcept { return sz_; }

    constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return p_; }
    constexpr const_iterator end()   const noexcept { return p_ + sz_; }

    constexpr char operator[](std::size_t n) const
    {
        return n < sz_ ? p_[n] : throw std::out_of_range("static_string");
    }
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, static_string const& s)
{
    return os.write(s.data(), s.size());
}

/// \brief Get the name of a type
template <class T>
static_string typeName()
{
#ifdef __clang__
    static_string p = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    return static_string(p.data() + 30, p.size() - 30 - 1);
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    static_string p = __FUNCSIG__;
    return static_string(p.data() + 37, p.size() - 37 - 7);
#endif

}

namespace details
{
    template <class Enum>
    struct EnumWrapper
    {
        template < Enum enu >
        static static_string name()
        {
#ifdef __clang__
            static_string p = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
            static_string enumType = typeName<Enum>();
            return static_string(p.data() + 73 + enumType.size(), p.size() - 73 - enumType.size() - 1);
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
            static_string p = __FUNCSIG__;
            static_string enumType = typeName<Enum>();
            return static_string(p.data() + 57 + enumType.size(), p.size() - 57 - enumType.size() - 7);
#endif
        }
    };
}

/// \brief Get the name of an enum value
template <typename Enum, Enum enu>
static_string enumName()
{
    return details::EnumWrapper<Enum>::template name<enu>();
}

enum class Color
{
    Blue = 0,
    Yellow = 1
};


int main() 
{
    std::cout << "_" << typeName<Color>() << "_"  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "_" << enumName<Color, Color::Blue>() << "_"  << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code above has only been tested on Clang (see https://ideone.com/je5Quv) and VS2015, but should be adaptable to other compilers by fiddling a bit with the integer constants. Of course, it still uses macros under the hood, but at least one doesn't need access to the enum implementation.

Comment: This fails with g++ 6.3.0 and C++14.

Comment: Interesting because the enum can be declared normally without having to wrap it in a macro. Though I don't like the compiler-dependencies and magic constants.

Comment: This doesn't work for an arbitrary enum value supplied at runtime (e.g. in a variable).

Answer (score 3):

I took the idea from @antron and implemented it differently: generating a true *enum class*.

This implementation meets all the requirements listed in original question but currently has only one **real limitation**: it assumes the enum values are either not provided or, if provided, must start with 0 and go up sequentially without gaps.

This is not an intrinsic limitation - simply that I don't use ad-hoc enum values. If this is needed, one can replace vector lookup with traditional switch/case implementation.

The solution uses some c++17 for inline variables but this can be easily avoided if needed. It also uses **boost:trim** because of simplicity.

Most importantly, it takes only 30 lines of code and no black magic macros.
The code is below. It's meant to be put in header and included in multiple compilation modules.

It can be used the same way as was suggested earlier in this thread:

```
ENUM(Channel, int, Red, Green = 1, Blue)
std::out << "My name is " << Channel::Green;
//prints My name is Green
```

Pls let me know if this is useful and how it can be improved further.

---

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>   
struct EnumSupportBase {
  static std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string s, char delim) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        auto pos = item.find_first_of ('=');
        if (pos != std::string::npos)
            item.erase (pos);
        boost::trim (item);
        tokens.push_back(item);
    }
    return tokens;
  }
};
#define ENUM(EnumName, Underlying, ...) \
    enum class EnumName : Underlying { __VA_ARGS__, _count }; \
    struct EnumName ## Support : EnumSupportBase { \
        static inline std::vector<std::string> _token_names = split(#__VA_ARGS__, ','); \
        static constexpr const char* get_name(EnumName enum_value) { \
            int index = (int)enum_value; \
            if (index >= (int)EnumName::_count || index < 0) \
               return "???"; \
            else \
               return _token_names[index].c_str(); \
        } \
    }; \
    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const EnumName & es) { \
        return os << EnumName##Support::get_name(es); \
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as you are okay with writing a separate `.h/.cpp` pair for each queryable enum, this solution works with nearly the same syntax and capabilities as a regular c++ enum:

```
// MyEnum.h
#include <EnumTraits.h>
#ifndef ENUM_INCLUDE_MULTI
#pragma once
#end if

enum MyEnum : int ETRAITS
{
    EDECL(AAA) = -8,
    EDECL(BBB) = '8',
    EDECL(CCC) = AAA + BBB
};
```

The `.cpp` file is 3 lines of boilerplate:

```
// MyEnum.cpp
#define ENUM_DEFINE MyEnum
#define ENUM_INCLUDE <MyEnum.h>
#include <EnumTraits.inl>
```

Example usage:

```
for (MyEnum value : EnumTraits<MyEnum>::GetValues())
    std::cout << EnumTraits<MyEnum>::GetName(value) << std::endl;
```

## Code

This solution requires 2 source files:

```
// EnumTraits.h
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

#define ETRAITS
#define EDECL(x) x

template <class ENUM>
class EnumTraits
{
public:
    static const std::vector<ENUM>& GetValues()
    {
        return values;
    }

    static ENUM GetValue(const char* name)
    {
        auto match = valueMap.find(name);
        return (match == valueMap.end() ? ENUM() : match->second);
    }

    static const char* GetName(ENUM value)
    {
        auto match = nameMap.find(value);
        return (match == nameMap.end() ? nullptr : match->second);
    }

public:
    EnumTraits() = delete;

    using vector_type = std::vector<ENUM>;
    using name_map_type = std::unordered_map<ENUM, const char*>;
    using value_map_type = std::unordered_map<std::string, ENUM>;

private:
    static const vector_type values;
    static const name_map_type nameMap;
    static const value_map_type valueMap;
};

struct EnumInitGuard{ constexpr const EnumInitGuard& operator=(int) const { return *this; } };
template <class T> constexpr T& operator<<=(T&& x, const EnumInitGuard&) { return x; }
```

...and

```
// EnumTraits.inl
#define ENUM_INCLUDE_MULTI

#include ENUM_INCLUDE
#undef ETRAITS
#undef EDECL

using EnumType = ENUM_DEFINE;
using TraitsType = EnumTraits<EnumType>;
using VectorType = typename TraitsType::vector_type;
using NameMapType = typename TraitsType::name_map_type;
using ValueMapType = typename TraitsType::value_map_type;
using NamePairType = typename NameMapType::value_type;
using ValuePairType = typename ValueMapType::value_type;

#define ETRAITS ; const VectorType TraitsType::values
#define EDECL(x) EnumType::x <<= EnumInitGuard()
#include ENUM_INCLUDE
#undef ETRAITS
#undef EDECL

#define ETRAITS ; const NameMapType TraitsType::nameMap
#define EDECL(x) NamePairType(EnumType::x, #x) <<= EnumInitGuard()
#include ENUM_INCLUDE
#undef ETRAITS
#undef EDECL

#define ETRAITS ; const ValueMapType TraitsType::valueMap
#define EDECL(x) ValuePairType(#x, EnumType::x) <<= EnumInitGuard()
#include ENUM_INCLUDE
#undef ETRAITS
#undef EDECL
```

## Explanation

This implementation exploits the fact that the braced list of elements of an enum definition can also be used as a braced initializer list for class member initialization.

When `ETRAITS` is evaluated in the context of `EnumTraits.inl`, 
it expands out to a static member definition for the `EnumTraits<>` class.

The `EDECL` macro transforms each enum member into initializer list values which subsequently get passed into the member constructor in order to populate the enum info.

The `EnumInitGuard` class is designed to consume the enum initializer values and then collapse - leaving a pure list of enum data.

## Benefits

- `c++`-like syntax
- Works identically for both `enum` and `enum class` (*almost)
- Works for `enum` types with any numeric underlying type
- Works for `enum` types with automatic, explicit, and fragmented initializer values
- Works for mass renaming (intellisense linking preserved)
- Only 5 preprocessor symbols (3 global)

`*` *In contrast to `enums`, initializers in `enum class` types that reference other values from the same enum must have those values fully qualified*

## Disbenefits

- Requires a separate `.h/.cpp` pair for each queryable `enum`
- Depends on convoluted `macro` and `include` magic
- Minor syntax errors explode into much larger errors
- Defining `class` or `namespace` scoped enums is nontrivial
- No compile time initialization

## Comments

Intellisense will complain a bit about private member access when opening up `EnumTraits.inl`, but since the expanded macros are actually defining class members, that isn't actually a problem.

The `#ifndef ENUM_INCLUDE_MULTI` block at the top of the header file is a minor annoyance that could probably be shrunken down into a macro or something, but it's small enough to live with at its current size.

Declaring a namespace scoped enum requires that the enum first be forward declared inside its namespace scope, then defined in the global namespace. Additionally, any enum initializers using values of the same enum must have those values fully qualified.

```
namespace ns { enum MyEnum : int; }
enum ns::MyEnum : int ETRAITS
{
    EDECL(AAA) = -8,
    EDECL(BBB) = '8',
    EDECL(CCC) = ns::MyEnum::AAA + ns::MyEnum::BBB
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple solution with one big constraint: you can't assign custom values to `enum` values, but with the right regex, you could. you could also add a map to translate them back to `enum` values without much more effort:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& s, 
                               const std::regex& delim = std::regex(",\\s*"))
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> cont;
    copy(regex_token_iterator<string::const_iterator>(s.begin(), s.end(), delim, -1), 
         regex_token_iterator<string::const_iterator>(),
         back_inserter(cont));
    return cont;
}

#define EnumType(Type, ...)     enum class Type { __VA_ARGS__ }

#define EnumStrings(Type, ...)  static const std::vector<std::string> \
                                Type##Strings = split(#__VA_ARGS__);

#define EnumToString(Type, ...) EnumType(Type, __VA_ARGS__); \
                                EnumStrings(Type, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Usage example:

```
EnumToString(MyEnum, Red, Green, Blue);
```

Comment: Thank you Malem for your innovative idea. I have edited your answer to improve readability. I hope you like my changes. Please continue to improve your answer: (1) extend the section *"Usage example"* with something like `auto name = MyEnumStrings["Red"];` -- (2) Why do you use `enum class`? -- (3) Do you support `enum class MyEnum : char { Red, Green, Blue };`? -- (4) Explain function `split()` -- (5) Do you need parameter `const std::regex& delim`? -- (6) What about generating `MyEnumStrings` at compilation time? => Can you use `constexpr`? ... Cheers :-)

Comment: I really like this approach. Really short and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a reflection library, like [Ponder](https://billyquith.github.io/ponder/):

```
enum class MyEnum
{
    Zero = 0,
    One  = 1,
    Two  = 2
};

ponder::Enum::declare<MyEnum>()
    .value("Zero", MyEnum::Zero)
    .value("One",  MyEnum::One)
    .value("Two",  MyEnum::Two);

ponder::EnumObject zero(MyEnum::Zero);

zero.name(); // -> "Zero"
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this approach is already covered in one of the other answers (actually it is, see below). I encountered the problem many times and didnt find a solution that did not use obfuscated macros or third party libraries. Hence I decided to write my own obfuscated macro version.

What I want to enable is the equivalent of

```
enum class test1 { ONE, TWO = 13, SIX };

std::string toString(const test1& e) { ... }

int main() {
    test1 x;
    std::cout << toString(x) << "\n";
    std::cout << toString(test1::TWO) << "\n";
    std::cout << static_cast<std::underlying_type<test1>::type>(test1::TWO) << "\n";
    //std::cout << toString(123);// invalid
}
```

which should print

```
ONE
TWO
13
```

I am not a fan of macros. However, unless c++ natively supports converting enums to strings one has to use some sort of code generation and/or macros (and I doubt this will happen too soon). I am using a [X-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro):

```
// x_enum.h
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>
#define x_begin enum class x_name {
#define x_val(X) X
#define x_value(X,Y) X = Y
#define x_end };
x_enum_def
#undef x_begin
#undef x_val
#undef x_value
#undef x_end

#define x_begin inline std::string toString(const x_name& e) { \
                static std::map<x_name,std::string> names = { 
#define x_val(X)      { x_name::X , #X }
#define x_value(X,Y)  { x_name::X , #X }
#define x_end }; return names[e]; }
x_enum_def
#undef x_begin
#undef x_val
#undef x_value
#undef x_end
#undef x_name
#undef x_enum_def
```

Most of it is defining and undefining symbols that the user will pass as parameter to the X-marco via an include. The usage is like this

```
#define x_name test1
#define x_enum_def x_begin x_val(ONE) , \
                           x_value(TWO,13) , \
                           x_val(SIX) \
                   x_end
#include "x_enum.h"
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/A6OELZbsL2Aukd1u)

Note that I didnt include choosing the underlying type yet. I didnt need it so far, but it should be straight forward to modify to code to enable that.

Only after writing this I realized that it is rather similar to [eferions answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43136999/4117728). Maybe I read it before and maybe it was the main source of inspiration. I was always failing in understanding X-macros until I wrote my own ;).

Answer (score 2):

My solution, using a preprocessor define.

You can check this code on https://repl.it/@JomaCorpFX/nameof#main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <regex>

typedef std::string String;
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;

class Strings
{
public:
    static String TrimStart(const std::string& data)
    {
        String s = data;
        s.erase(s.begin(), std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](unsigned char ch) {
            return !std::isspace(ch);
        }));
        return s;
    }

    static String TrimEnd(const std::string& data)
    {
        String s = data;
        s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), [](unsigned char ch) {
            return !std::isspace(ch);
        }).base(),
            s.end());
        return s;
    }

    static String Trim(const std::string& data)
    {
        return TrimEnd(TrimStart(data));
    }

    static String Replace(const String& data, const String& toFind, const String& toReplace)
    {
        String result = data;
        size_t pos = 0;
        while ((pos = result.find(toFind, pos)) != String::npos)
        {
            result.replace(pos, toFind.length(), toReplace);
            pos += toReplace.length();
            pos = result.find(toFind, pos);
        }
        return result;
    }

};

static String Nameof(const String& name)
{
    std::smatch groups;
    String str = Strings::Trim(name);
    if (std::regex_match(str, groups, std::regex(u8R"(^&?([_a-zA-Z]\w*(->|\.|::))*([_a-zA-Z]\w*)$)")))
    {
        if (groups.size() == 4)
        {
            return groups[3];
        }
    }
    throw std::invalid_argument(Strings::Replace(u8R"(nameof(#). Invalid identifier "#".)", u8"#", name));
}

#define nameof(name) Nameof(u8## #name ## s)
#define cnameof(name) Nameof(u8## #name ## s).c_str()

enum TokenType {
    COMMA,
    PERIOD,
    Q_MARK
};

struct MyClass
{
    enum class MyEnum : char {
        AAA = -8,
        BBB = '8',
        CCC = AAA + BBB
    };
};

int main() {
    String greetings = u8"Hello"s;
    std::cout << nameof(COMMA) << std::endl;
    std::cout << nameof(TokenType::PERIOD) << std::endl;
    std::cout << nameof(TokenType::Q_MARK) << std::endl;
    std::cout << nameof(int) << std::endl;
    std::cout << nameof(std::string) << std::endl;
    std::cout << nameof(Strings) << std::endl;
    std::cout << nameof(String) << std::endl;
    std::cout << nameof(greetings) << std::endl;
    std::cout << nameof(&greetings) << std::endl;
    std::cout << nameof(greetings.c_str) << std::endl;
    std::cout << nameof(std::string::npos) << std::endl;
    std::cout << nameof(MyClass::MyEnum::AAA) << std::endl;
    std::cout << nameof(MyClass::MyEnum::BBB) << std::endl;
    std::cout << nameof(MyClass::MyEnum::CCC) << std::endl;


    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
COMMA
PERIOD
Q_MARK
int
string
Strings
String
greetings
greetings
c_str
npos
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Clang

[image: clang]

Visual C++

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT: check below for a newer version

As mentioned above, [N4113](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4113.pdf) is the final solution to this matter, but we'll have to wait more than a year to see it coming out.

Meanwhile, if you want such feature, you'll need to resort to "simple" templates and some preprocessor magic.

#### Enumerator

```
template<typename T>
class Enum final
{
    const char* m_name;
    const T m_value;
    static T m_counter;

public:
    Enum(const char* str, T init = m_counter) : m_name(str), m_value(init) {m_counter = (init + 1);}

    const T value() const {return m_value;}
    const char* name() const {return m_name;}
};

template<typename T>
T Enum<T>::m_counter = 0;

#define ENUM_TYPE(x)      using Enum = Enum<x>;
#define ENUM_DECL(x,...)  x(#x,##__VA_ARGS__)
#define ENUM(...)         const Enum ENUM_DECL(__VA_ARGS__);
```

#### Usage

```
#include <iostream>

//the initialization order should be correct in all scenarios
namespace Level
{
    ENUM_TYPE(std::uint8)
    ENUM(OFF)
    ENUM(SEVERE)
    ENUM(WARNING)
    ENUM(INFO, 10)
    ENUM(DEBUG)
    ENUM(ALL)
}

namespace Example
{
    ENUM_TYPE(long)
    ENUM(A)
    ENUM(B)
    ENUM(C, 20)
    ENUM(D)
    ENUM(E)
    ENUM(F)
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Level::Enum lvl = Level::WARNING;
    Example::Enum ex = Example::C;
    std::cout << lvl.value() << std::endl; //2
    std::cout << ex.value() << std::endl; //20
}
```

#### Simple explaination

`Enum<T>::m_counter` is set to 0 inside each namespace declaration.
(*Could someone point me out where ^^this behaviour^^ is mentioned on the standard?*)
The preprocessor magic automates the declaration of enumerators.

#### Disadvantages

- It's not a true `enum` type, therefore not promotable to int
- Cannot be used in switch cases

---

## Alternative solution

This one sacrifices line numbering (not really) **but can be used on switch cases**.

```
#define ENUM_TYPE(x) using type = Enum<x>
#define ENUM(x)      constexpr type x{__LINE__,#x}

template<typename T>
struct Enum final
{
    const T value;
    const char* name;

    constexpr operator const T() const noexcept {return value;}
    constexpr const char* operator&() const noexcept {return name;}
};
```

### Errata

`#line 0` conflicts with `-pedantic` on GCC and clang.

#### Workaround

Either start at `#line 1` and subtract 1 from `__LINE__`.
Or, don't use `-pedantic`.
And while we're at it, avoid VC++ at all costs, it has always been a joke of a compiler.

#### Usage

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Level
{
    ENUM_TYPE(short);
    #line 0
    ENUM(OFF);
    ENUM(SEVERE);
    ENUM(WARNING);
    #line 10
    ENUM(INFO);
    ENUM(DEBUG);
    ENUM(ALL);
    #line <next line number> //restore the line numbering
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << Level::OFF << std::endl;   // 0
    std::cout << &Level::OFF << std::endl;  // OFF

    std::cout << Level::INFO << std::endl;  // 10
    std::cout << &Level::INFO << std::endl; // INFO

    switch(/* any integer or integer-convertible type */)
    {
    case Level::OFF:
        //...
        break;

    case Level::SEVERE:
        //...
        break;

    //...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Real-life implementation and use

[r3dVoxel - Enum](https://github.com/bit2shift/r3dVoxel/blob/c76af954c55480a33c0213c1c25c121fa33043fd/inc/r3dVoxel/util/Enum.hpp)
[r3dVoxel - ELoggingLevel](https://github.com/bit2shift/r3dVoxel/blob/c76af954c55480a33c0213c1c25c121fa33043fd/inc/r3dVoxel/ILogger.hpp#L22)

#### Quick Reference

[#line *lineno* -- cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/line)

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is based on a `std::array<std::string,N>` for a given enum.

For `enum` to `std::string` conversion we can just cast the enum to `size_t` and lookup the string from the array. The operation is O(1) and requires no heap allocation.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/enum.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

#define STRINGIZE(s, data, elem) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem)

// ENUM
// ============================================================================
#define ENUM(X, SEQ) \
struct X {   \
    enum Enum {BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(SEQ)}; \
    static const std::array<std::string,BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(SEQ)> array_of_strings() { \
        return {{BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_TRANSFORM(STRINGIZE, 0, SEQ))}}; \
    } \
    static std::string to_string(Enum e) { \
        auto a = array_of_strings(); \
        return a[static_cast<size_t>(e)]; \
    } \
}
```

For `std::string` to `enum` conversion we would have to make a linear search over the array and cast the array index to `enum`.

Try it here with usage examples: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4212f93bee65076

**Edit:** Reworked my solution so the custom Enum can be used inside a class.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer. Please rework your proposal in order to use your macro within a class. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00d362eba836d04b Moreover try to use `constexpr`and `noexept` keywords when possible. Cheers :-)

Comment: The question didn't specify this requisite.

Comment: Question updated (see example). Two other requirements: (1) support type of enum and (2) values can be different from sequence 0, 1, 2...

Comment: I reworked my solution to it can be used inside a class. I haven't figured out how to make the values different from 0,1,2,.. though.

Comment: Hi FKaria. Thank you very much for your rework. I did some changes in order to support several enums within the same class, and also to support the `enum class X : Type` format. Please review my contribution: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b02db9190d3491a3 What do you think about my changes? Do you have any idea to support values set within enum? Example `enum E{A=3, B=6, C=A-B};` Cheers

Comment: Several enums within the same class should be supported with my solution. Although you need to use the X::Enum syntax which may be a bit ugly. I wasn't aware of the possibility to specify a type for the enums, that's a nice addition. Regarding the enum assignment, I haven't looked a it yet but I guess it will require some macro of the style `ENUM(X, (A,3)(B,6)(C,A-B))` if it can be done at all.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions using enum within class/struct (struct defaults with public members) and overloaded operators:

```
struct Color
{
    enum Enum { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
    Enum e;

    Color() {}
    Color(Enum e) : e(e) {}

    Color operator=(Enum o) { e = o; return *this; }
    Color operator=(Color o) { e = o.e; return *this; }
    bool operator==(Enum o) { return e == o; }
    bool operator==(Color o) { return e == o.e; }
    operator Enum() const { return e; }

    std::string toString() const
    {
        switch (e)
        {
        case Color::RED:
            return "red";
        case Color::GREEN:
            return "green";
        case Color::BLUE:
            return "blue";
        default:
            return "unknown";
        }
    }
};
```

From the outside it looks nearly exactly like a class enum:

```
Color red;
red = Color::RED;
Color blue = Color::BLUE;

cout << red.toString() << " " << Color::GREEN << " " << blue << endl;
```

This will output "red 1 2". You could possibly overload << to make blue output a string (although it might cause ambiguity so not possible), but it wouldn't work with Color::GREEN since it doesn't automatically convert to Color.

The purpose of having an implicit convert to Enum (which implicitly converts to int or type given) is to be able to do:

```
Color color;
switch (color) ...
```

This works, but it also means that this work too:

```
int i = color;
```

With an enum class it wouldn't compile.
You ought to be careful if you overload two functions taking the enum and an integer, or remove the implicit conversion...

Another solution would involve using an actual enum class and static members:

```
struct Color
{
    enum class Enum { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
    static const Enum RED = Enum::RED, GREEN = Enum::GREEN, BLUE = Enum::BLUE;

    //same as previous...
};
```

It possibly takes more space, and is longer to make, but causes a compile error for implicit int conversions. I'd use this one because of that!

There's surely overhead with this though, but I think it's just simpler and looks better than other code I've seen. There's also potential for adding functionality, which could all be scoped within the class.

**Edit**: this works and most can be compiled before execution:

```
class Color
{
public:
    enum class Enum { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
    static const Enum RED = Enum::RED, GREEN = Enum::GREEN, BLUE = Enum::BLUE;

    constexpr Color() : e(Enum::RED) {}
    constexpr Color(Enum e) : e(e) {}

    constexpr bool operator==(Enum o) const { return e == o; }
    constexpr bool operator==(Color o) const { return e == o.e; }
    constexpr operator Enum() const { return e; }

    Color& operator=(Enum o) { const_cast<Enum>(this->e) = o; return *this; }
    Color& operator=(Color o) { const_cast<Enum>(this->e) = o.e; return *this; }

    std::string toString() const
    {
        switch (e)
        {
        case Enum::RED:
            return "red";
        case Enum::GREEN:
            return "green";
        case Enum::BLUE:
            return "blue";
        default:
            return "unknown";
        }
    }
private:
    const Enum e;
};
```

Comment: This is very interesting :-) However your current version implies you have to manually write the stuff `case Enum::RED: return "red";`. The question is about automatizing this stuff by the compiler (at compilation time). The idea of the question is to only change or add enum values without having to update the stuff `toString()`. Do you see? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/hutorny/5d8b1caac02710b9549be213d7d436e5) provides a simple mapping based on C++ variadic templates.

This is a C++17-simplified version of the type-based map from the [gist](https://gist.github.com/hutorny/5d8b1caac02710b9549be213d7d436e5):

```
#include <cstring> // http://stackoverflow.com/q/24520781

template<typename KeyValue, typename ... RestOfKeyValues>
struct map {
  static constexpr typename KeyValue::key_t get(const char* val) noexcept {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(RestOfKeyValues)==0)  // C++17 if constexpr
      return KeyValue::key; // Returns last element
    else {
      static_assert(KeyValue::val != nullptr,
                  "Only last element may have null name");
      return strcmp(val, KeyValue::val()) 
            ? map<RestOfKeyValues...>::get(val) : KeyValue::key;
    }
  }
  static constexpr const char* get(typename KeyValue::key_t key) noexcept {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(RestOfKeyValues)==0)
      return (KeyValue::val != nullptr) && (key == KeyValue::key)
            ? KeyValue::val() : "";
    else
      return (key == KeyValue::key) 
            ? KeyValue::val() : map<RestOfKeyValues...>::get(key);
  }
};

template<typename Enum, typename ... KeyValues>
class names {
  typedef map<KeyValues...> Map;
public:
  static constexpr Enum get(const char* nam) noexcept {
    return Map::get(nam);
  }
  static constexpr const char* get(Enum key) noexcept {
    return Map::get(key);
  }
};
```

An example usage:

```
enum class fasion {
    fancy,
    classic,
    sporty,
    emo,
    __last__ = emo,
    __unknown__ = -1
};

#define NAME(s) static inline constexpr const char* s() noexcept {return #s;}
namespace name {
    NAME(fancy)
    NAME(classic)
    NAME(sporty)
    NAME(emo)
}

template<auto K, const char* (*V)()>  // C++17 template<auto>
struct _ {
    typedef decltype(K) key_t;
    typedef decltype(V) name_t;
    static constexpr key_t  key = K; // enum id value
    static constexpr name_t val = V; // enum id name
};

typedef names<fasion,
    _<fasion::fancy, name::fancy>,
    _<fasion::classic, name::classic>,
    _<fasion::sporty, name::sporty>,
    _<fasion::emo, name::emo>,
    _<fasion::__unknown__, nullptr>
> fasion_names;
```

The `map<KeyValues...>` can be used in both directions:

- `fasion_names::get(fasion::emo)`
- `fasion_names::get("emo")`

This example is available on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/YaAzt3)

```
int main ()
{
  constexpr auto str = fasion_names::get(fasion::emo);
  constexpr auto fsn = fasion_names::get(str);
  return (int) fsn;
}
```

Result from `gcc-7 -std=c++1z -Ofast -S`

```
main:
        mov     eax, 3
        ret
```

Comment: Very interesting meta-programming way. I have tried to simplify a bit the answer to be autonomous (without dependency on Gist link). In order to be concise and understandable I have finally edited a lot your answer. Do you still agree with my changes? Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

(Analogue of https://stackoverflow.com/a/54967187/2338477, slightly modified).

Here is my own solution with minimum define magic and support of individual enum assignments.

Here is header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <regex>

template <class Enum>
class EnumReflect
{
public:
    static const char* getEnums() { return ""; }
};

//
//  Just a container for each enumeration type.
//
template <class Enum>
class EnumReflectBase
{
public:
    static std::map<std::string, int> enum2int;
    static std::map<int, std::string> int2enum;

    static void EnsureEnumMapReady( const char* enumsInfo )
    {
        if (*enumsInfo == 0 || enum2int.size() != 0 )
            return;

        // Should be called once per each enumeration.
        std::string senumsInfo(enumsInfo);
        std::regex re("^([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]+) *=? *([^,]*)(,|$) *");     // C++ identifier to optional " = <value>"
        std::smatch sm;
        int value = 0;

        for (; regex_search(senumsInfo, sm, re); senumsInfo = sm.suffix(), value++)
        {
            string enumName = sm[1].str();
            string enumValue = sm[2].str();

            if (enumValue.length() != 0)
                value = atoi(enumValue.c_str());

            enum2int[enumName] = value;
            int2enum[value] = enumName;
        }
    }
};

template <class Enum>
std::map<std::string, int> EnumReflectBase<Enum>::enum2int;

template <class Enum>
std::map<int, std::string> EnumReflectBase<Enum>::int2enum;


#define DECLARE_ENUM(name, ...)                                         \
    enum name { __VA_ARGS__ };                                          \
    template <>                                                         \
    class EnumReflect<##name>: public EnumReflectBase<##name> {         \
    public:                                                             \
        static const char* getEnums() { return #__VA_ARGS__; }          \
    };




/*
    Basic usage:

    Declare enumeration:

DECLARE_ENUM( enumName,

    enumValue1,
    enumValue2,
    enumValue3 = 5,

    // comment
    enumValue4
);

    Conversion logic:

    From enumeration to string:

        printf( EnumToString(enumValue3).c_str() );

    From string to enumeration:

       enumName value;

       if( !StringToEnum("enumValue4", value) )
            printf("Conversion failed...");
*/

//
//  Converts enumeration to string, if not found - empty string is returned.
//
template <class T>
std::string EnumToString(T t)
{
    EnumReflect<T>::EnsureEnumMapReady(EnumReflect<T>::getEnums());
    auto& int2enum = EnumReflect<T>::int2enum;
    auto it = int2enum.find(t);

    if (it == int2enum.end())
        return "";

    return it->second;
}

//
//  Converts string to enumeration, if not found - false is returned.
//
template <class T>
bool StringToEnum(const char* enumName, T& t)
{
    EnumReflect<T>::EnsureEnumMapReady(EnumReflect<T>::getEnums());
    auto& enum2int = EnumReflect<T>::enum2int;
    auto it = enum2int.find(enumName);

    if (it == enum2int.end())
        return false;

    t = (T) it->second;
    return true;
}
```

And here is example test application:

```
DECLARE_ENUM(TestEnum,
    ValueOne,
    ValueTwo,
    ValueThree = 5,
    ValueFour = 7
);

DECLARE_ENUM(TestEnum2,
    ValueOne2 = -1,
    ValueTwo2,
    ValueThree2 = -4,
    ValueFour2
);

void main(void)
{
    string sName1 = EnumToString(ValueOne);
    string sName2 = EnumToString(ValueTwo);
    string sName3 = EnumToString(ValueThree);
    string sName4 = EnumToString(ValueFour);

    TestEnum t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 = ValueOne;
    bool b1 = StringToEnum(sName1.c_str(), t1);
    bool b2 = StringToEnum(sName2.c_str(), t2);
    bool b3 = StringToEnum(sName3.c_str(), t3);
    bool b4 = StringToEnum(sName4.c_str(), t4);
    bool b5 = StringToEnum("Unknown", t5);

    string sName2_1 = EnumToString(ValueOne2);
    string sName2_2 = EnumToString(ValueTwo2);
    string sName2_3 = EnumToString(ValueThree2);
    string sName2_4 = EnumToString(ValueFour2);

    TestEnum2 t2_1, t2_2, t2_3, t2_4, t2_5 = ValueOne2;
    bool b2_1 = StringToEnum(sName2_1.c_str(), t2_1);
    bool b2_2 = StringToEnum(sName2_2.c_str(), t2_2);
    bool b2_3 = StringToEnum(sName2_3.c_str(), t2_3);
    bool b2_4 = StringToEnum(sName2_4.c_str(), t2_4);
    bool b2_5 = StringToEnum("Unknown", t2_5);
```

Updated version of same header file will be kept here:

https://github.com/tapika/cppscriptcore/blob/master/SolutionProjectModel/EnumReflect.h

Answer (score 1):

[enum_name](https://github.com/mguludag/enum_name) is header only, supports >=C++11 and easy to use library. It's simple and supports enum to/from string conversion. During development I aimed to support C++11, using with no macros and simplicity.

#### [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/cKsEo353T)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "enum_name.hpp"


enum class rgb_color { red, green, blue, unknown = -1};

// you can specialize enum ranges with specialize struct per enum types (option 1)
namespace mgutility{
    template<>
    struct enum_range<rgb_color>
    {
        static constexpr auto min = -1;
        static constexpr auto max = 3;
    };
}

// you can specialize enum ranges with overload per enum types (option 2)
auto enum_name = [](rgb_color c){ return mgutility::enum_name<-1, 3>(c); };


int main()
{
    auto x = rgb_color::blue;
    auto y = mgutility::to_enum<rgb_color>("green");
    
    // default signature: enum_name<min_value = -128, max_value = 128, Enum typename>(Enum&&) 
    // Changing max_value to not too much greater than enum's max value, it will compiles faster
    std::cout << mgutility::enum_name(x) << '\n'; // will print "blue" to output
    
    // calling specialized enum ranges function for rgb_color type
    // will print "green" to output, if y can't convert to rgb_color prints "unknown"
    std::cout << enum_name(y.value_or(rgb_color::unknown)) << '\n'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library for solving this problem, everything happens in compiling time, except for getting the message.

### Usage:

Use macro `DEF_MSG` to define a macro and message pair:

```
DEF_MSG(CODE_OK,   "OK!")
DEF_MSG(CODE_FAIL, "Fail!")
```

`CODE_OK` is the macro to use, and `"OK!"` is the corresponding message.

Use `get_message()` or just `gm()` to get the message:

```
get_message(CODE_FAIL);  // will return "Fail!"
gm(CODE_FAIL);           // works exactly the same as above
```

Use `MSG_NUM` to find out how many macros have been defined. This will automatically increse, you don't need to do anything.

Predefined messages:

```
MSG_OK:     OK
MSG_BOTTOM: Message bottom
```

Project: [libcodemsg](https://github.com/madwyn/libcodemsg)

---

The library doesn't create extra data. Everything happens in compiling time. In `message_def.h`, it generates an `enum` called `MSG_CODE`; in `message_def.c`, it generates a variable holds all the strings in `static const char* _g_messages[]`.

In such case, the library is limited to create one `enum` only. This is ideal for return values, for example:

```
MSG_CODE foo(void) {
    return MSG_OK; // or something else
}

MSG_CODE ret = foo();

if (MSG_OK != ret) {
    printf("%s\n", gm(ret););
}
```

Another thing I like this design is you can manage message definitions in different files.

---

I found the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907160/how-to-convert-enum-names-to-string-in-c) looks much better.

Comment: Hi Madwyn. Thanks for your idea. But how it works? What is the overhead? (zero overhead or does it creates extra data?). Your proposition seems fine, but unfortunately, one statement `DEF_MSG` has to be used/updated/maintained for each `enum` value :-/ And this is what ideally we would like to stop doing... Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @olibre. Please check the updated answer. I don't see overhead here, except a function call is needed for accessing the strings. `DEF_MSG` makes the `enum` closely paired with the message, although it has some limitations.

Comment: Thank you for the appended explanation in your answer :-) Your lib is fine but cannot be used for multiple enums :-/ What about the support of [`enum class` (C++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) ? You can use `constexpr` to limit `_g_messages` at run-time. Support multiple `enum` types (avoiding `_g_messages`) using meta-programming (type conveying {enum-type, enum-value}) or maybe [template variables (C++14)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template). I think your lib does not (yet?) fit the C++11/14/17 requirements. What do you think? Cheers ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the following up. I learned something new today! The enum class and template variables look good. I think my answer was a little bit "off topic" as it was C flavoured.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define ENUM_MAKE(TYPE, ...) \
        enum class TYPE {__VA_ARGS__};\
        struct Helper_ ## TYPE { \
            static const String& toName(TYPE type) {\
                int index = static_cast<int>(type);\
                return splitStringVec()[index];}\
            static const TYPE toType(const String& name){\
                static std::unordered_map<String,TYPE> typeNameMap;\
                if( typeNameMap.empty() )\
                {\
                    const StringVector& ssVec = splitStringVec();\
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < ssVec.size(); ++i)\
                        typeNameMap.insert(std::make_pair(ssVec[i], static_cast<TYPE>(i)));\
                }\
                return typeNameMap[name];}\
            static const StringVector& splitStringVec() {\
                static StringVector typeNameVector;\
                if(typeNameVector.empty()) \
                {\
                    typeNameVector = StringUtil::split(#__VA_ARGS__, ",");\
                    for (auto& name : typeNameVector)\
                    {\
                        name.erase(std::remove(name.begin(), name.end(), ' '),name.end()); \
                        name = String(#TYPE) + "::" + name;\
                    }\
                }\
                return typeNameVector;\
            }\
        };


using String = std::string;
using StringVector = std::vector<String>;

   StringVector StringUtil::split( const String& str, const String& delims, unsigned int maxSplits, bool preserveDelims)
    {
        StringVector ret;
        // Pre-allocate some space for performance
        ret.reserve(maxSplits ? maxSplits+1 : 10);    // 10 is guessed capacity for most case

        unsigned int numSplits = 0;

        // Use STL methods 
        size_t start, pos;
        start = 0;
        do 
        {
            pos = str.find_first_of(delims, start);
            if (pos == start)
            {
                // Do nothing
                start = pos + 1;
            }
            else if (pos == String::npos || (maxSplits && numSplits == maxSplits))
            {
                // Copy the rest of the string
                ret.push_back( str.substr(start) );
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Copy up to delimiter
                ret.push_back( str.substr(start, pos - start) );

                if(preserveDelims)
                {
                    // Sometimes there could be more than one delimiter in a row.
                    // Loop until we don't find any more delims
                    size_t delimStart = pos, delimPos;
                    delimPos = str.find_first_not_of(delims, delimStart);
                    if (delimPos == String::npos)
                    {
                        // Copy the rest of the string
                        ret.push_back( str.substr(delimStart) );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ret.push_back( str.substr(delimStart, delimPos - delimStart) );
                    }
                }

                start = pos + 1;
            }
            // parse up to next real data
            start = str.find_first_not_of(delims, start);
            ++numSplits;

        } while (pos != String::npos);



        return ret;
    }
```

example

```
ENUM_MAKE(MY_TEST, MY_1, MY_2, MY_3)


    MY_TEST s1 = MY_TEST::MY_1;
    MY_TEST s2 = MY_TEST::MY_2;
    MY_TEST s3 = MY_TEST::MY_3;

    String z1 = Helper_MY_TEST::toName(s1);
    String z2 = Helper_MY_TEST::toName(s2);
    String z3 = Helper_MY_TEST::toName(s3);

    MY_TEST q1 = Helper_MY_TEST::toType(z1);
    MY_TEST q2 = Helper_MY_TEST::toType(z2);
    MY_TEST q3 = Helper_MY_TEST::toType(z3);
```

automatically ENUM_MAKE macro generate 'enum class' and helper class with 'enum reflection function'.

In order to reduce mistakes, at once Everything is defined with only one ENUM_MAKE.

The advantage of this code is automatically created for reflection and a close look at macro code ,easy-to-understand code. 'enum to string' , 'string to enum' performance both is algorithm O(1).

Disadvantages is when first use , helper class for enum relection 's string vector and map is initialized.
but If you want you'll also be pre-initialized. –

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: hey guys , i am sorry   i don't speak english very well.

Comment: automatically ENUM_MAKE macro generate  'enum class' and  helper class with 'enum reflection function'.  /

In order to reduce mistakes, at once  Everything is defined with only one ENUM_MAKE.

The advantage of this code is automatically created for reflection
and   a close look at macro code ,easy-to-understand code.
 
'enum to string' , 'string to enum'  performance both  is  algorith O(1).

Disadvantages is when first use ,  helper class for enum relection 's   string vector and map is initialized.

but  If you want you'll also be pre-initialized.

Comment: Hi desperado_98. Thank you for your contribution. Please edit your answer and insert in it your comment content. The compiler can compute your example at compile-time if you use some meta-programming tricks and `constexpr`. I mean the functions `toName()` and `toType()` can be evaluated during the compilation and not during the execution (run-time). Please adopt C++11/14/17 style in your answer. Cheers ;-)

Comment: Moreover: Is your macro compatible with   
`enum class MyEnum : short { A, B, C };` ?

Comment: olibre,    i don't know well macro but  it did not seem to recusive.   therefore  __VA_ARGS__ macro must be parsing in runtime.  i could not solve in compile time.

Comment: enum class MyEnum : short { A, B, C };  <-  you can test...  , i did not test not yet   but it seem no problem

Comment: Macros not only impede readability once they reach a certain level of complexity but the error messages created are especially hideous.
Moreover, it's so easy to break a complex macro's intent unless it's done really meticulously.
I personally try to keep macros around three to five lines max and only use them where there is a real benefit without any reasonable alternatives...

Answer (score 0):

my solution is without macro usage.

advantages:

- you see exactly what you do
- access is with hash maps, so good for many valued enums
- no need to consider order or non-consecutive values
- both enum to string and string to enum translation, while added enum value must be added in one additional place only

disadvantages:

- you need to replicate all the enums values as text
- access in hash map must consider string case
- maintenance if adding values is painful - must add in both enum and direct translate map

so... until the day that C++ implements the C# Enum.Parse functionality, I will be stuck with this:

```
            #include <unordered_map>

            enum class Language
            { unknown, 
                Chinese, 
                English, 
                French, 
                German
                // etc etc
            };

            class Enumerations
            {
            public:
                static void fnInit(void);

                static std::unordered_map <std::wstring, Language> m_Language;
                static std::unordered_map <Language, std::wstring> m_invLanguage;

            private:
                static void fnClear();
                static void fnSetValues(void);
                static void fnInvertValues(void);

                static bool m_init_done;
            };

            std::unordered_map <std::wstring, Language> Enumerations::m_Language = std::unordered_map <std::wstring, Language>();
            std::unordered_map <Language, std::wstring> Enumerations::m_invLanguage = std::unordered_map <Language, std::wstring>();

            void Enumerations::fnInit()
            {
                fnClear();
                fnSetValues();
                fnInvertValues();
            }

            void Enumerations::fnClear()
            {
                m_Language.clear();
                m_invLanguage.clear();
            }

            void Enumerations::fnSetValues(void)
            {   
                m_Language[L"unknown"] = Language::unknown;
                m_Language[L"Chinese"] = Language::Chinese;
                m_Language[L"English"] = Language::English;
                m_Language[L"French"] = Language::French;
                m_Language[L"German"] = Language::German;
                // and more etc etc
            }

            void Enumerations::fnInvertValues(void)
            {
                for (auto it = m_Language.begin(); it != m_Language.end(); it++)
                {
                    m_invLanguage[it->second] = it->first;
                }
            }

            // usage -
            //Language aLanguage = Language::English;
            //wstring sLanguage = Enumerations::m_invLanguage[aLanguage];

            //wstring sLanguage = L"French" ;
            //Language aLanguage = Enumerations::m_Language[sLanguage];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, yet another option. A typical use case is where you need constants for the HTTP verbs as well as using its string version values.

The example:

```
int main () {

  VERB a = VERB::GET;
  VERB b = VERB::GET;
  VERB c = VERB::POST;
  VERB d = VERB::PUT;
  VERB e = VERB::DELETE;


  std::cout << a.toString() << std::endl;

  std::cout << a << std::endl;

  if ( a == VERB::GET ) {
    std::cout << "yes" << std::endl;
  }

  if ( a == b ) {
    std::cout << "yes" << std::endl;
  }

  if ( a != c ) {
    std::cout << "no" << std::endl;
  }

}
```

The VERB class:

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------
class VERB {

private:

  // private constants
  enum Verb {GET_=0, POST_, PUT_, DELETE_};

  // private string values
  static const std::string theStrings[];

  // private value
  const Verb value;
  const std::string text;

  // private constructor
  VERB (Verb v) :
  value(v), text (theStrings[v])
  {
    // std::cout << " constructor \n";
  }

public:

  operator const char * ()  const { return text.c_str(); }

  operator const std::string ()  const { return text; }

  const std::string toString () const { return text; }

  bool operator == (const VERB & other) const { return (*this).value == other.value; }

  bool operator != (const VERB & other) const { return ! ( (*this) == other); }

  // ---

  static const VERB GET;
  static const VERB POST;
  static const VERB PUT;
  static const VERB DELETE;

};

const std::string VERB::theStrings[] = {"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"};

const VERB VERB::GET = VERB ( VERB::Verb::GET_ );
const VERB VERB::POST = VERB ( VERB::Verb::POST_ );
const VERB VERB::PUT = VERB ( VERB::Verb::PUT_ );
const VERB VERB::DELETE = VERB ( VERB::Verb::DELETE_ );
// end of file
```

Comment: To reduce memory usage, you may replace member `const std::string text` by just `theStrings[v]`. However the question is about the features from C++11/C++14/C++17/C++20 to avoid having to write such class by hand :-/

Answer (score 0):

My answer is here.

You can get enum value names and these indices simultaneously as deque of string.

This method only needs little copy and paste and edit.

Obtained result needs type-casting from size_t to enum class type when you need enum class type value, but I think it is a very portable and powerful way to treat enum class.

```
enum class myenum
{
  one = 0,
  two,
  three,
};

deque<string> ssplit(const string &_src, boost::regex &_re)
{
  boost::sregex_token_iterator it(_src.begin(), _src.end(), _re, -1);
  boost::sregex_token_iterator e;
  deque<string> tokens;
  while (it != e)
    tokens.push_back(*it++);
  return std::move(tokens);
}

int main()
{
  regex re(",");
  deque<string> tokens = ssplit("one,two,three", re);
  for (auto &t : tokens) cout << t << endl;
    getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My 3 cents, though this is not a complete match to what the op wants. Here is the relevant [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858141/conveniently-declaring-compile-time-strings-in-c/15863826#15863826).

```
namespace enums
{

template <typename T, T I, char ...Chars>
struct enums : std::integral_constant<T, I>
{
  static constexpr char const chars[sizeof...(Chars)]{Chars...};
};

template <typename T, T X, typename S, std::size_t ...I>
constexpr auto make(std::index_sequence<I...>) noexcept
{
  return enums<T, X, S().chars[I]...>();
}

#define ENUM(s, n) []() noexcept{\
  struct S { char const (&chars)[sizeof(s)]{s}; };\
  return enums::make<decltype(n), n, S>(\
    std::make_index_sequence<sizeof(s)>());}()

#define ENUM_T(s, n)\
  static constexpr auto s ## _tmp{ENUM(#s, n)};\
  using s ## _enum_t = decltype(s ## _tmp)

template <typename T, typename ...A, std::size_t N>
inline auto map(char const (&s)[N]) noexcept
{
  constexpr auto invalid(~T{});

  auto r{invalid};

  return
    (
      (
        invalid == r ?
          r = std::strncmp(A::chars, s, N) ? invalid : A{} :
          r
      ),
      ...
    );
}

}

int main()
{
  ENUM_T(echo, 0);
  ENUM_T(cat, 1);
  ENUM_T(ls, 2);

  std::cout << echo_enum_t{} << " " << echo_enum_t::chars << std::endl;

  std::cout << enums::map<int, echo_enum_t, cat_enum_t, ls_enum_t>("ls")) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

So you generate a type, that you can convert to an integer and/or a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly comfortable with all of the fancy frameworks (macros and templates and classes) that are being proposed with this, since I think using them makes the code much harder to understand, and can increase compile times and hide bugs. In general, I want a SIMPLE solution to this problem. Adding an extra 100 lines of code is not simple.

The example given in the original question was quite close to code that I actually use in production. Instead, I would just like to propose a few small improvements to the original example lookup function:

```
const std::string& magic(MyClass::MyEnum e)
{
    static const std::string OUT_OF_RANGE = "Out of range";
    #define ENTRY(v) { MyClass::MyEnum::v, "MyClass::MyEnum::" #v }
    static const std::unordered_map<MyClass::MyEnum, std::string> LOOKUP {
        ENTRY(AAA),
        ENTRY(BBB),
        ENTRY(CCC),
    };
    #undef ENTRY
    auto it  = LOOKUP.find(e);
    return ((it != LOOKUP.end()) ? it->second : OUT_OF_RANGE);
}
```

Specifically:

1. Internal data structures are now 'static' and 'const'. These are
   unchanging, so there is no need to construct these on every call to
   the function, and to do so would be very inefficient. Instead, these are
   constructed on the first call to the function only.
2. Return value is now 'const std::string&'. This
   function will only return references to already-allocated
   std::string objects with 'static' lifetime, so there is no need to
   copy them when returning.
3. Map type is now 'std::unordered_map'
   for O(1) access instead of std::map's O(log(N)) access.
4. Use of the ENTRY macro allows somewhat more concise code and also avoids potential
   problems from typos made while entering names in the string literals. (If the
   programmer enters an invalid name, a compiler error will result.)

Answer (score -4):

You can use a `select()` function, which is really just a short-hand switch; it is not a solution in the true sense of the word, but it makes life easier:

```
enum
{
  NORMAL,
  INVALID
} state(NORMAL);

//std::cout << (state ? "INVALID" : "NORMAL") << std::endl;
std::cout << select(state, "NORMAL", "INVALID") << std::endl;
```

`select()` functions are common in SIMD/GPU programming. They are generalizations of the ternary `?:` operator. You can also view `select()` as a functional array (a function implementing an array data structure).

Here's a full [example](https://github.com/user1095108/generic/blob/master/dispatch.cpp).

EDIT: `select()` does not need to be elaborate, here's a simple one:

```
char const* select(std::size_t const i, char const* const (&a)[]) { return a[i]; }
```