# calling enum << operator for string composition

Tags: c++, c++11, operators

Suppose we have enum with implemented `operator<<` converting enum value to string.  Is it possible to call this operator during string construction or something similar? My current approach uses `std::stringstream` calling << on enum and extracting string from `std::stringstream`. Is there any other way? Using `std::cout <<` is not an option.

Example code:

```
enum class Status {
    OK,
    ERROR
}

::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& os, Status status)
{
    switch (status) {
        case Status::OK:
            return os << "OK";
        case Status::ERROR:
            return os << "ERROR";
}
```

Usage:

```
Status s = Status::OK;
std::stringstream stream;
stream << s;
std::string statusString = s.str().c_str();
```

Comment: You could always make a `std::map` then you could use this for both retrieving the string and defining your `operator<<` if you want `std::map<Status, std::string> statuses{ {Status::OK, "OK"}, {Status::ERROR, "ERROR"} };`

Comment: possible duplicate of [enum to string in modern C++ and future C++17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828957/enum-to-string-in-modern-c-and-future-c17)

Comment: You are missing default case, but you are doing it ok. Or the trick with std::map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, here is no any elegant solution as you want.

If we only could, we might use a user defined conversion but it needs to be a non-static member function which is impossible with `enums`.

But you may always use argument-dependent lookup like you do with your `operator<<`.

Or if you want string, make a map and put desired string-equivalent there.

Comment: Well thats disappointing and i've just earned downvovte as a reward rofl :D