# Get & Set for Enum in C++

Tags: c++, enums

I have a class named School and one of its members is an enum 'SchoolType' that has two possible values: Primary and Secondary. Here is what I have for the enum in my School header file:

```
 enum class SchoolType {
    Primary = 1,
    Secondary = 2
};
```

And in my main C++ file I have a function `ReadSchool` that reads in all of School's members from user input. All of the other members are `int` and `string` values so I have no trouble reading in those but I don't know what to do for the enum. My best idea was to do this:

```
School ReadSchool()
{
    School tempSchool;
    int type;
    cout << "Name of School: ";
    tempSchool.SetName(GetString());
    cout << endl << "Type of School (1 = Primary, 2 = Secondary): ";
    cin >> type;
    if (type = 2)
        tempSchool.SetTypeSchool(2);        
    else
        tempSchool.SetTypeSchool(1);
    return tempSchool;
}
```

Putting an int value into my `SetTypeSchool()` doesn't work, but nor does writing either `Primary` or `Secondary`. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 if that makes any difference. Can anyone offer some clarity or a better way to set my enum value? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SchoolType GetSchoolType(string input)
{
    // DeHumanize our input
    if(input == "Primary")
    {
        return SchoolType::Primary;
    }
    else if(input == "Secondary")
    {
        return SchoolType::Secondary;
    }

    return SchoolType.None; // or throw an exception, or return a default SchoolType; up to you
}
```

Comment: `SchoolType.Primary` is not C++.

Comment: @aschepler Sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write streaming operators for your enumeration type, after which they can be used naturally with `<<` and `>>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

enum class SchoolType {
    Primary = 1,
    Secondary = 2
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, SchoolType s)
{
    return os << (s == SchoolType::Primary ? "Primary" :
                  s == SchoolType::Secondary ? "Secondary" :
                  throw std::runtime_error("invalid SchoolType output"));
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, SchoolType& s)
{
    std::string word;
    if (is >> word)
    {
        if (word == "Primary") { s = SchoolType::Primary; return is; }
        if (word == "Secondary") { s = SchoolType::Secondary; return is; }
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << SchoolType::Primary << ' ' << SchoolType::Secondary << '\n';
    std::istringstream iss("Primary Secondary Fail");
    SchoolType a, b;
    iss >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << " good:" << iss.good() << '\n';
    iss >> a;
    std::cout << "good:" << iss.good() << '\n';
}
```

See the code run [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4161804496219490).

CAUTION: The simple streaming to `std::string` then checking for an enumeration identifier requires a little care in use: the identifier must be delimited by whitespace (e.g. space, tab, newline) or End-Of-File; trailing characters like punctuation or brackets/braces/parentheses will be sucked into the string, then the comparison will fail and throw.

A more complex but robust version is available [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d1f718e35dc79d7), using a supporting class `Identifier` for character-by-character input and `unget()` at the first character not legal in an identifier.  With this, in `operator>>(std::istream& is, SchoolType& s)` just replace `std::string word;` with `Identifier word;`.

```
struct Identifier : std::string { };

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Identifier& idn)
{
    idn.clear();
    char c;
    if (is >> c)
    {
        if (!std::isalnum(c))
            is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        else
        {
            idn += c;
            while (is.get(c))
                if (std::isalnum(c) || c == '_')
                    idn += c;
                else
                {
                    is.unget();
                    break;
                }
            // hit EOF, is.get(c) will have left fail condition set
            is.clear(); // doesn't matter that we also clear EOF
        }
    }
    return is;
}
```

(In practice, I prefer to write to-string and from-string functions, *then* write the streaming operators using those: it's sometimes more convenient e.g. if you quickly want a string representation without creating streams).

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several problems, for example `if (type = 2)` should be `if (type == 2)`. To pass the actual constants, you need to refer to them as `SchoolType::Primary` and `SchoolType::Secondary`. If your `SetSchoolType`'s argument is of type `SchoolType`, those are the two constants it will accept.

Several answerers mentioned converting the value from string, including defining a stream operator for the purpose. If you are not against using an external library, you can achieve that with syntax like this:

```
#include <enum.h>
BETTER_ENUM(SchoolType, int, Primary = 1, Secondary = 2)

// ...later...

SchoolType  type;
cin >> type;    // Expects to read the string "Primary" or "Secondary".
```

The rest of the usage is, for the most part, like a normal enum class.

The library can be found here: https://github.com/aantron/better-enums. It consists of a single header file. The license is BSD, so use it as you wish. There is a Stack Overflow answer explaining the core of the library's internals: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31362042/2482998.

Due to an unfortunate limitation, you won't be able to declare `SchoolType` directly inside `School` as you describe, but there is an easy workaround shown in the `README`.

Disclaimer: I am the author.

Answer (score 0):

You should allow the user to enter strings (e.g. "Primary" or "Secondary") and then have a function that converts the strings to the `enum`.

The function serves two purposes:

1. Validates the input
2. Does the necessary conversion from `string` to `enum`.

Comment: So I should do `tempSchool.SetTypeSchool(GetType(type));`? But in `GetType(string type)` how would I actually make the string into an enum? `SchoolType tempType = temp; return tempType;`?

Comment: @LiliaO. Check each input string against "Primary" and return Primary if they match.  And do the same for "Secondary".  Since there are only two enums an if statement will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to replace:

```
 SetSchoolType(2);
```

with

```
 SetSchoolType(static_cast<SchoolType>(2));
```

Comment: Assuming that this is correct, why is it correct?  How does it solve the OPs problem?

Comment: I was suggesting that `SetSchoolType(2)` could be replaced with `SetSchoolType(static_cast<SchoolType>(2))`