# compile time typeid for every type

Tags: c++, c++14

I'd like a `constexpr` function that will return me a unique id for every C++ type, something like this:

```
using typeid_t = uintptr_t;

template <typename T>
constexpr typeid_t type_id() noexcept
{
  return typeid_t(type_id<T>);
}

int main()
{
  ::std::cout << ::std::integral_constant<typeid_t, type_id<float>()>{} << ::std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

But I get an error:

```
t.cpp: In function 'int main()':
t.cpp:23:69: error: conversion from pointer type 'typeid_t (*)() noexcept {aka long unsigned int (*)() noexcept}' to arithmetic type 'typeid_t {aka long unsigned int}' in a constant-expression
   ::std::cout << ::std::integral_constant<typeid_t, type_id<float>()>{} << ::std::endl;
                                                                     ^
t.cpp:23:69: note: in template argument for type 'long unsigned int'
```

Is there a workaround or another way?

Comment: How's taking a pointer to the function here: (`typeid_t(type_id<T>)`) is supposed to work? Why don't you just use [typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator?

Comment: Because its not constexpr?

Comment: Only if you apply it to the polymorphic type

Comment: Can you give a short example where typeid would work as a template parameter

Comment: Note that `typeid(expr).hash_code()` is almost what you want, but it is not a constexpr.

Comment: @okovko Thank you, but I did want a `constexpr` solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use some tricks as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35943472/2969631).

There's even a library called [ctti](https://github.com/Manu343726/ctti) that utilizes the same trick, it should work out of the box

```
static_assert(ctti::type_id<int>() != ctti::type_id<float>(), "compile-time type-id comparison");

constexpr auto hash = ctti::type_id<int>().hash();
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way, this time involving a `constexpr` function, would be to use a well known hash function like in the following example (where I used the FNV v1a):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

static constexpr uint32_t offset = 2166136261u;
static constexpr uint32_t prime = 16777619u;

constexpr uint32_t helper(uint32_t partial, const char *str) {
    return str[0] == 0 ? partial : helper((partial^str[0])*prime, str+1);
}

constexpr uint32_t hash_str(const char *input) {
    return helper(offset, input);
}

struct MyClassA { static constexpr uint32_t type = hash_str("MyClassA"); };
struct MyClassB { static constexpr uint32_t type = hash_str("MyClassB"); };

int main() {
    std::cout << "MyClassA: " << MyClassA::type << std::endl;
    std::cout << "MyClassB: " << MyClassB::type << std::endl;
}
```

The drawbacks:

- conflicts can happen
- error-prone (at least, from my point of view)
- pretty invasive a sollution

The main advantage is that you can use this solution if you need the types to be the same over different executions (as an example, if you have to store them somewhere and use them again after a while).

Comment: That's why I consider it error-prone, it's pretty easy to forget adding your string time to time. Anyway, that solution offers the chance to have persistent types, so it depends of what's the goal you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<auto Id>
struct counter {
    using tag = counter;

    struct generator {
        friend consteval auto is_defined(tag)
        { return true; }
    };
    friend consteval auto is_defined(tag);

    template<typename Tag = tag, auto = is_defined(Tag{})>
    static consteval auto exists(auto)
    { return true; }

    static consteval auto exists(...)
    { return generator(), false; }
};

template<typename T, auto Id = int{}>
consteval auto unique_id() {
    if constexpr (counter<Id>::exists(Id)) {
        return unique_id<T, Id + 1>();
    } else {
        return Id;
    }
}

static_assert(unique_id<int>() == 0);
static_assert(unique_id<int>() == 0);
static_assert(unique_id<double>() == 1);
static_assert(unique_id<float>() == 2);
static_assert(unique_id<char>() == 3);

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GY74xvq5q

consteval since -std=c++20, based on:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74453799/475145

It can be adapted to c++17 just changing consteval to constexpr.
In the need to adapt to c++14 auto on templated must be changed, and if constexpr replaced.

It's guaranteed to generate the same ids for any compilation as long as the types always follow the same initialization order.

Answer (score 1):

This's not a `constexpr` function, but if there is not the constraint for the types to be persistent over multiple executions, you can use `CRTP` idiom as an alternative approach to achieve the same result.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

struct BaseClass {
protected:
    static std::size_t next() noexcept {
        static std::size_t counter = 0;
        return counter++;
    }
};

template<class D>
struct Base: public BaseClass {
    static std::size_t type() noexcept {
        static std::size_t type_ = BaseClass::next();
        return type_;
    }
};

struct A: public Base<A> { };
struct B: public Base<B> { };

int main() {
    std::cout << A::type() << std::endl;
    std::cout << B::type() << std::endl;
}
```

This way you have a base class from which to derive for all those types for which you would like to have an unique identifier.

Comment: I like this. A class template like that could support all types, though not at compile time.

Comment: Another drawback is that a class can easily have different types during different executions, so this is a good solution only if you need consistency over a single execution of your software.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template <class C>
struct TypeIdentifier {
    constexpr static int _id{};
    constexpr static auto id() {
        return &_id;
    }
};


int main() {
    constexpr auto const id_int = TypeIdentifier<int>::id();
    constexpr auto const id_int_again = TypeIdentifier<int>::id();
    constexpr auto const id_float = TypeIdentifier<float>::id();
    constexpr auto const id_double = TypeIdentifier<double>::id();
    constexpr auto const id_char = TypeIdentifier<char>::id();

    // Test equality
    static_assert(id_int == id_int_again);
    static_assert(id_int != id_float);

    std::cout << id_int << std::endl;
    std::cout << id_float << std::endl;
    std::cout << id_double << std::endl;
    std::cout << id_char << std::endl;
    
    assert(id_int == id_int_again);
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sETffooxT

There is this nice way to get a compile time type id.
The values will mostly change between one compilation and another due to the use of addresses, but for the purpose of hashing/switching/jumps it's a safe bet.