# Comparing two constexpr pointers is not constexpr?

Tags: c++, pointers, constexpr

I am looking for a way to map types to numeric values at compile time, ideally without using a hash as proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36122101/2173029) answer.

Since pointers can be `constexpr`, I tried this:

```
struct Base{};
template<typename T> struct instance : public Base{};

template<typename T>
constexpr auto type_instance = instance<T>{};

template<typename T>
constexpr const Base* type_pointer = &type_instance<T>;

constexpr auto x = type_pointer<int> - type_pointer<float>; // not a constant expression
```

Both gcc and clang reject this code because `type_pointer<int> - type_pointer<float>` is not a constant expression, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/MShPiH), for instance.

Why though?

I can understand that the difference between both values is not going to be stable from one compilation to the next, but within one compilation, it should be `constexpr`, IMHO.

Comment: Is `auto x` declared and initialised in a static/global context or is it inside a function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Subtraction of two non-null pointers which do not point into the same array or to the same object (including one-past-the-array/object) is undefined behavior, see [[expr.add]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add) (in particular paragraph 5 and 7) of the C++17 standard (final draft).

Expressions which would have core undefined behavior<sup>[1]</sup> if evaluated are *never* constant expressions, see [[expr.const]/2.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.6).

Therefore `type_pointer<int> - type_pointer<float>` cannot be a constant expression, because the two pointers are to unrelated objects.

Since `type_pointer<int> - type_pointer<float>` is not a constant expression, it cannot be used to initialize a `constexpr` variable such as

```
constexpr auto x = type_pointer<int> - type_pointer<float>;
```

Trying to use a non-constant expression as initializer to a `constexpr` variable makes the program ill-formed and requires the compiler to print a diagnostic message. This is what the error message you are seeing is.

Basically compilers are required to diagnose core undefined behavior when it appears in purely compile-time contexts.

You can see that there will be no error if the pointers are to the same object, e.g.:

```
constexpr auto x = type_pointer<int> - type_pointer<int>;
```

Here the subtraction is well-defined and the initializer is a constant expression. So the code will compile (and won't have undefined behavior). `x` will have a well-defined value of `0`.

---

Be aware that if you make `x` non-`constexpr` the compiler won't be required to diagnose the undefined behavior and to print a diagnostic message anymore. It is therefore likely to compile.

Subtracting unrelated pointers is still *undefined* behavior though, not only *unspecified* behavior. Therefore you will loose any guarantee on what the resulting program will do. It does not only mean that you will get different values for `x` in each compilation/execution of the code.

---

<sup>[1] *Core undefined behavior* here refers to undefined behavior in the core language, in contrast with undefined behavior due to use of the standard library. It is *unspecified* whether undefined behavior as specified for the library causes an (otherwise constant) expression to not be a constant expression, see final sentence before the example in [[expr.const]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.22).</sup>

Comment: This seems like a bit of a cheating answer. ;) Technically correct, but it seems unlikely that the practical cause of this error is the UB (which a program _has_, or rather _hasn't_; you can't "cause" it) - perhaps the question should give an example where the pointers are into an array, instead. I bet that has the same problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 - Why is it cheating? The UB is literally what must be diagnosed here https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.6

Comment: What if the `float*` is pointing to the same memory (integer object) as the `int*`? Then they're both pointing to the same object, and we are not accessing that integer from the `float*` since we never dereferenced it. Is this still undefined behavior?

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 A simple modification showing that this is the error is to subtract pointers to the same object instead, see https://godbolt.org/z/2MpFvX. I am not sure what you are trying to get at.

Comment: @Ayxan I am not sure what you are referring to. There are no `int*` or `float*` in OP's code. I have added an example that *does* work to my answer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @walnut Oh wow, okay then yeah.  I wasn't trying to "get at" anything beyond literally what I said... but I was wrong. :)

Comment: (I suggest quoting expr.const/2.6 in the answer as this was news to me and could be news to others...)

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I put in a link to the section.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I have added an explanation.

Comment: Actually _"will not be ill-formed anymore"_ is wrong. The ill-formedness category will simply change to "ill-formed, no diagnostic required", which implies undefined behavior.

Comment: Great answer! Took me a while to find [expr.add](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#5) regarding the undefined behavior in pointer subtraction you mentioned. Maybe you could add that link, too?

Comment: @Rumburak I added a link to the C++17 version of that section, though the wording in the current draft that you linked is much clearer.