# typeid(*this).name() returns null pointer on delegated constructor of std::exception subclass

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance, language-lawyer, clang++

I found a strange behavior running this small snippet of code compiled with clang:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <typeinfo>

struct Foo : public std::exception {
    std::string myString;
    Foo(const std::string& str) : myString(str) {}
    Foo() : Foo(typeid(*this).name()) {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    std::cout << f.myString;
}
```

The instruction `typeid(*this).name()` called inside the delegated constructor returns a `nullptr` that causes a segmentation fault. During the delegated constructor call `std::exception` base class is not yet initialized and this seems the cause of this behavior.

I'm wondering if this code is ill-formed for some reason, or this behavior is expected.

I cannot reproduce this bug with g++, where the code runs fine.

It also occurs only if the base class is std::exception, in any other case it works fine even on clang.

Comment: The error kinda makes sense. The base class isn't initialized yet at that point, since the base constructor wasn't executed yet.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the strange part is that it only occurs when the base class is std::exception and the code is compiled with clang++, otherwise I was not able to reproduce it.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @HolyBlackCat. The usual C++ rules still apply. `*this` is a pointer dereference, which has the usual caveats. If there's no object at that address (yet), you can only use the resulting reference in a limited number of ways. `typeid` is not one of them:  it queries the dynamic type of an object, so there has to be an object. So this question is perhaps a bit convoluted, but the logic seems straightforward. Undefined Behavior, anything can happen and actual results can be pure coincidence.

Comment: It fails with any base class with virtual members: https://godbolt.org/z/Kh4G3fYG3, MSVC shows the same behaviour. Though even with a non-virtual base it is still undefined behaviour it just happens to work

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this means that the problem is that the default constructor delegates the construction, right? So if you change it to: `Foo() : myString(typeid(*this).name()) {}`, then the base will be (default-)constructed first and it is well defined.

Comment: @Frodyne Yes, correct. The argument in the delegating constructor is evaluated before the constructor of the base class is called, while the initializer of `myString` is evaluated afterwards.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am not sure that last part is correct. If the type is non-polymorphic, the operand of `typeid` is not supposed to be evaluated. How would one then determine whether the expression refers to the object under construction, so that the special rules apply?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has undefined behavior. `typeid` is allowed to be applied to the object under construction in the constructor, also the member initializer list, but only after construction of all base class subobjects has completed. See [[class.base.init]/16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.base.init#16.sentence-3).

If `typeid(*this)` was used after the base classes have been constructed, then [[class.cdtor]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.cdtor#5) would describe the behavior of `typeid` in this specific situation. (It would return the `type_info` corresponding to `Foo` irregardless of whether `Foo` is the most-derived type.)

---

I think this is only supposed to apply though if `*this` has polymorphic type, i.e. `Foo` has a (inherited) virtual member function (`std::exception::what` and `std::exception::~exception` in your case). The current wording doesn't seem to clearly separate this, but for non-polymorphic types the expression shouldn't even be evaluated, so it can't matter that `*this` refers to the object under construction. There are related open CWG issues, e.g. [CWG issue 1517](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1517.html).

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the semantics of `typeid(*this)`, an alternative would be shifting more of the work to compile-time. Specifically:

1. Implement a constexpr function which gets you the name of a type - and I mean a *proper* name, not some annoying code. You can find an implementation in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35941045/can-i-obtain-c-type-names-in-a-constexpr-way/56600402).
2. Use the type name in the classes inheriting `Foo` to construct your `Foo` base.

You can automate this further using the CRTP and writing `class MyException : Foo<MyException>`, with the `Foo` template constructor extracting the template argument type from its own class type. And this will all happen at compile time!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for UB is using the object before even its very first subobject is constructed.
In general, built-in RTTI can not be properly usef inside the constructor. Virtual functions are bound early; because virtual table only contains current class info; derived class is not constructed yet. I would put the dynamic calculations in the `what` virtual method:

```
struct Foo : public std::exception {
    consteval Foo(char const * const str) : name{str} {};
    consteval Foo() = default;
    const char* what() const noexcept override {
        return name.empty()?
               typeid(*this).name():
               name;
    };
private:
    std::string_view const name;
};
```