# How to invoke the overloaded << operator defined externally?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

My reference is to the following post (and the answer by `Jamboree`):

[Can I obtain C++ type names in a constexpr way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35941045/can-i-obtain-c-type-names-in-a-constexpr-way/35943472#35943472)

I copied the source code mentioned in the answer but not sure how I can invoke the overloaded `<< operator` function defined externally?

I tried something along the lines of

```
ostream& os << getname<char>();
```

but this results in the following compilation error:

```
error: expected initializer before '<<' token
```

TIA

Comment: try `cout << getname<char>();`

Comment: While your link going dead is not a concern, a question should still provide enough context to be understandable without following a link. Extracting enough code from the linked answer for a [mre] would probably be enough. (A sample `getName` could simply return some fixed name.)

Comment: By the way, if you put enough work into a [mre], you might find yourself with something closer to `#include <ostream> int main() { std::ostream& os << 1; }` which would eliminate the need to reference the other question. ;)