# Using macro to split a given argument

Tags: c++, boost-preprocessor

Lets say we have a macro like this:

```
#define SOME_MACRO(a) ...do stuff
```

Now, calling the macro in this way:

```
SOME_MACRO(argName=1)
```

It should return only the first part of the given argument before = (just 'argName' in this case). Is it possible?
Thank you in advance

Thank you all, this is my full problem:
I'm using this macro to create an enum and a function to get the enum values as strings:

```
#define RA_MAKE_ENUMERATOR_S1(r, data, elem) case elem : return BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem);
#define RA_MAKE_ENUMERATOR(name, enumerators)                                   \
enum name                                                                   \
{                                                                           \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(enumerators)                                          \
};                                                                          \
                                                                            \
inline const std::string ValueToString(name v)                              \
{                                                                           \
    switch (v)                                                              \
    {                                                                       \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(RA_MAKE_ENUMERATOR_S1, name, enumerators) \
    }                                                                       \
}   

RA_MAKE_ENUMERATOR(eTest, (ONE) (TWO))
```

This outputs the following code:

```
enum eTest
{
    ONE, 
    TWO
}; 
inline const std::string ValueToString(eTest v)
{
    switch (v)
    {
         case ONE  : return "ONE"; 
         case TWO  : return "TWO";
    }
}
```

Which is perfect. But what is I want to assign a specific value to ONE and TWO like:

```
enum eTest
{
    ONE = 2, 
    TWO = 4
};
```

I tried calling the macro as

```
RA_MAKE_ENUMERATOR(eTest, (ONE=2) (TWO=2))
```

The enumerator is ok but of course the ValueToString function is messed up

Comment: No. But you can simply change the design. To get good suggestions about that it can help to explain what this is used for.

Comment: Such is beyond the c-preprocessor's capabilities. Sorry!

Comment: Why do you need such? Sounds like a XY problem.

Comment: "Lets say we have a macro" - how about we say you *don't* and then use proper C++ rather than the hell that is the pre-processor?  Never use macros when you can avoid them.

Comment: "Lets say we have a macro". Now you have *two* problems...

Comment: Why do you use evil macros?  Look up `template` if the data type changes or `inline` functions for small content functions.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828957/enum-to-string-in-modern-c-and-future-c17-c20/31362042#31362042) gives a possible alternative. [Here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8qNzdomBY9nGWhj2) is an example heavily based on that answer.

Comment: @jv_ This is interesting. I'll give it a try. TYVM for your help