# Properly overload << operator

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I'm quite new to c++ and my current problem is to output a **struct** using an overloaded operator.
I've tried my best, but apparently it is not enough. Anyone knows why my compiler keeps pushing out this mistake:
\main.cpp|16|error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream' and 'const Eyecolor')|

This is the corresponding code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum class Eyecolor {blue, brown, green};

struct PStruct {
    string surname;
    Eyecolor eyecolor;
    double height;
    bool gender;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PStruct& ps);
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PStruct& ps)
{
    os << ps.surname << '/' << ps.height << '/' << ps.gender << '/' << ps.eyecolor; //line 16
    return os;
}
void print(){
    cout << os;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure i defined the operator<< one line prior to that.

Anyway thanks for the answers in advance

Comment: You did not define the `operator<<` for your `enum Eyecolor`

Comment: E.g. exactly what the error states. `(operand types are 'std::basic_ostream' and 'const Eyecolor')` .You defined your operator on `PSStruct`. But your enum is a class-type. It needs its own operator if you want `<< ps.eyecolor` to work.

Comment: Well either as WhozCraig said, or you can make a switch(or if) instead of "<< ps.eyecolor", like:
    https://godbolt.org/z/TEf8bds8v

Comment: @MathiasJ; 1) your example is broken. 2) bad advice.

Comment: @user1810087 yes, because the example code given is broken? The question was related to a specific compiler error, this code fixes that compiler error. It does not fix that "void print(){
    cout << os;
}" is not compliable code, but no questions was asked in regards to that.

Answer (score 0):

A stripped down version of the error message:

```
no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' and 'const Eyecolor')
                                          ----------------------------> ^^
```

The error complains about missing `operator<<` for `Eyecolor`. The one you defined is for `PStruct` and tries to call the missing operator here:

```
os << ps.surname << '/' << ps.height << '/' << ps.gender << '/' << ps.eyecolor;
                                          --------------------> ^^
```

In the same way you defined one for `PStruct` you need to define one for `EyeColor`.

Enum to string conversion is a long standing annoyance in C++, you can see how much work one has to put into it to get a generic solution here: [enum to string in modern C++11 / C++14 / C++17 and future C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828957/enum-to-string-in-modern-c11-c14-c17-and-future-c20). Here I am not going into that, but merely show how to get the `operator<<` working.

Really no offense, but making the operator a friend smells like [Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). You probably have seen this in examples, and commonly the operator needs to be befriended, but there is no reason to do so in your code. Moreover `print()` has errors.

A fixed version could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum class Eyecolor {blue, brown, green};

struct PStruct {
    std::string surname;
    Eyecolor eyecolor;
    double height;
    bool gender;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Eyecolor ec){
    switch(ec){
        case Eyecolor::blue :
            os << "blue";
            break;
        case Eyecolor::brown :
            os << "brown";
            break;
        case Eyecolor::green :
            os << "green";
            break;
        default:
            os << "unknown color";
    }
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PStruct& ps)
{
    os << ps.surname << '/' << ps.height << '/' << ps.gender << '/' << ps.eyecolor;
    return os;
}
void print(const PStruct& ps){
    std::cout << ps;
}
```

PS:
[Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)