# Stringify each token in __VA_ARGS__ from a variadic macro

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, variadic-macros, boost-preprocessor

I am trying to *#stringify* each token in a `__VA_ARGS__` from a variadic macro.

The idea is to use these tokens as entries in an `enum` and also push them (*stringified*) to a `std::vector<std::string>`. Assuming the `enum` entries have default values, they would then map as indices in the vector.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define MAKE_ENUM_AND_STRINGS(...)\
    enum test_enum{ __VA_ARGS__ };\
    std::vector<std::string> test_vector{ /*bad*/__VA_ARGS__/*bad*/ }

void foo() {
    MAKE_ENUM_AND_STRINGS(a, b, c, d);
}
```

I have already read many posts about it and can't find a satisfying solution (I don't want to define 20+ macros to "parse" `__VA_ARGS__`) - I wonder if something new in C++20 or C++23 would make this possible ?

EDIT: I am now looking for a solution using `boost/preprocessor`.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html might help if you don't want to write loads of macros yourself

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'll accept a solution using boost if this solves it.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/variadic_macros.html

Comment: Rather than doing this in the preprocessor, it might make sense to stringify the entire list and then separate them out into a vector if that's easier to follow. That said, `__VA_OPT__` _is_ a new thing that _can_ be used to create a basic iteration tool pretty straightforwardly: https://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/blog/va-opt.html

Comment: @chris I need this to work at compile time.

Comment: @PinkTurtle, You can still do string processing at compile time. The catch right now is the workaround to store the final result, but you have the same problem if you want a compile-time result of PP-generated strings.

Comment: I would change the syntax to `MAKE_ENUM_AND_STRINGS( (a)(b)(c) )`, then this is easy (especially with boost.pp).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yep, pretty much where I'm at right now. I wonder if there is a way (using boost macros) to turn a `__VA_ARGS__` into SEQUENCE form (for example "a, b, c, d" into "(a)(b)(c)(d)") ?

Comment: That would be [`BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html). But it's not really viable long-term, if the next thing you want to add is manually setting enum values (parsing things like `a, b=42, c` quickly becomes a PITA, because values can contain `,`s and so on), while `(a)(b,42)(c)` is dead simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload the macro on number of arguments.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define FOREACH_STRINGIFY_1(a)       #a
#define FOREACH_STRINGIFY_2(a, ...)  #a, FOREACH_STRINGIFY_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_STRINGIFY_3(a, ...)  #a, FOREACH_STRINGIFY_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_STRINGIFY_4(a, ...)  #a, FOREACH_STRINGIFY_3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_STRINGIFY_N(_4,_3,_2,_1,N,...) \
        FOREACH_STRINGIFY##N
#define FOREACH_STRINGIFY(...)  \
        FOREACH_STRINGIFY_N(__VA_ARGS__,_4,_3,_2,_1) \
        (__VA_ARGS__)

#define MAKE_ENUM_AND_STRINGS(...) \
    enum test_enum{ __VA_ARGS__ }; \
    std::vector<std::string> test_vector{ \
         FOREACH_STRINGIFY(__VA_ARGS__) \
    }

int main() {
    MAKE_ENUM_AND_STRINGS(a, b, c, d);
    for (auto&& i : test_vector) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

I think this is an unusual way to have a way to stringify enums. I think usually X macros method is used. Consider using an existing stringifing enum library, instead of reinventing the wheel, there are so many of them, like [How to convert an enum to a string in modern C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828957/how-to-convert-an-enum-to-a-string-in-modern-c) .

---

> I am now looking for a solution using boost/preprocessor tho

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/list/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_list.hpp>

#define MAKE_ENUM_AND_STRINGS_CALLBACK(r, data, elem)  \
    BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem),

#define MAKE_ENUM_AND_STRINGS(...) \
    enum test_enum { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
    std::vector<std::string> test_vector{ \
        BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH( \
            MAKE_ENUM_AND_STRINGS_CALLBACK, \
            _, \
            BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_LIST(__VA_ARGS__) \
        ) \
    }

int main() {
    MAKE_ENUM_AND_STRINGS(a, b, c, d);
    for (auto&& i : test_vector) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I think this would work; I am now looking for a solution using boost/preprocessor tho.

Comment: `I am now looking for a solution using boost/preprocessor tho` So did you found it, or something?

Comment: not yet (someone closed the post :/), but I am getting close. I just need to find a way to convert a `__VA_ARGS__` in to boost PP "sequence". Then this will solve it : https://pastebin.com/LaRQa1LB

Comment: OK I have found it :-) BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/variadic_to_seq.html)